# AngularJS + ASP.NET Web API Cross-Domain Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angularjs

Moving forward with my mobile app development learning process, I've found a new obstacle: Cross-origin Request Sharing or CORS.

I am using a combination of AngularJS + jQuery Mobile (Cordova phone client) and ASP.NET Web API (backend). My issue is that I have not been able to complete a POST request (or any other type of request) to an API controller.

My AngularJS controller uses the `$http.post()` service method to call the Web API controller. However, Chrome debugger says that the call failed in an OPTIONS request (possibly the CORS preflight request).

I have implemented the CORS action selector from the following post: [Enabling CORS in Web API Project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a). Even tough I can call the api method from Fiddler, AngularJS keeps failing on the OPTIONS preflight request.

Is there anything I should be aware of about AngularJS and cross-domain calls? Any possible solution to my predicament?

Thanks.

Comment: [another angularjs question re: OPTIONS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Answer (score 11):

You can skip the preflight option request by using content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

**AngularJS:**

```
var user = {
   ID: 1,
   Name: 'test'
};

$http({
  url: "api.localhost/api/users/addUser",
  method: "POST",
  data: $.param(user),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  withCredentials: true,
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log(data);
})
```

**Web api:**

```
[HttpPost]
public string AddUser(User user)
{
    // Do something
    return user.Name + " added";
}
```

**Web.config**

```
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <handlers>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
                <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
                <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
```

Comment: this worked with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and without the web.config part

Answer (score 3):

While stumbling onto this issue with AngularJS 1.3 with Microsoft Web API 2 I found a simple solution to the CORS configuration issue.

- First from Nuget intall - Microsoft WebApi Cors

  ```
  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
  ```
- Then in your WebApiConfig.cs file:

  ```
  var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("www.my-angular-web-site.com", "*", "*");

  config.EnableCors(cors);
  ```

You can also enable CORS everywhere with a * instead of your web site but that defeats the purpose of CORS and opens up security holes - but you can do it for testing.

The WebApi.Cors assembly also lets you enable cors controller by controller or with other more granular details.  Other details can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#)  on the Web API site.

Comment: config.EnableCors(); 
should be
config.EnableCors(cors);

Answer (score 0):

Check out Thinktecture Cors objects, with those (nugettable) you can get full CORS support in WebApi without any code of your own.

Even with a correct CORS implementation I've had a really strange issue with IIS 7 that was solved by enabling all verbs for WebDav (yes, WebDav - don't ask me why I just followed instructions on a blog post :-D).

Do this:

- Open IIS manager, go to your application's Handler Mapping.
- Double click the WebDav handler
- Click "Request Restriction"
- On the "Verbs" tab, select "All verbs".

Again, no idea why WebApi uses WebDav, but this solved problems with POST and DELETE that wouldn't work in spite of a correct CORS implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly the developers while running there UI and service on Localhost face this issue - There are many ways in which this can be resolved - alot of the developers tend to fix it at browser level " but thats a security breach.

Correct method is to fix this at your Web Service Layer- Following video will explain and solve this

Watch [CORS- Implementing Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvs5-C7NoRs&t=132s) ("EXPLAINED - Cross Origin Resource Sharing")!