# jQuery CORS Content-type OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I have issue with sending AJAX body request using jQuery CORS with custom Content-type.
Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://some-other-domain/my-path",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    key: 1,
    key2: 2
  }),
  statusCode: {
    200: function(data) {
    }
  },
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  crossDomain: true
});
```

I need to set Content-type as "application/json" as it's require server side. But instead of sending request as POST
jQuery sends it's as OPTIONS.

Here's a headers:

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 EET
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BB9D6783E58FB0F2ADE1924A2F0CBA52; Path=/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 6233
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 14:41:13 GMT
```

Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /my-path HTTP/1.1
Host: MY-HOME-NAME
User-Agent: MY_USER_AGEMT
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: HERE-GOES-DOMAIN
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

CORS works great, all required headers are sends by server, but not if it sends by OPTIONS type.
Is it jQuery issue?

jQuery - 1.8.1

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This OPTIONS request is the CORS preflight request. It is a request that is sent to the server before the actual request in order to ask permissions to make the request. The custom Content-Type is in fact triggering the preflight. According to the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), any Content-Type *other* than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain triggers the preflight.

If you have no control over the remote server, then you'll need to either ask them to support CORS preflight, or try some other option such as JSON-P.

If you do have control over the remote server, you can change it to handle preflights. In order to handle a preflight request, you should send the following headers in the response to the OPTIONS request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

The response should be an HTTP 200. The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header can either echo the value of the `Access-Control-Request-Method`, or it can just be `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` to support all methods. The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header should echo the values in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header.

Once the browser receives those headers, it will make the actual request. You can learn more about CORS preflight requests here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: You. Are. A. Godsend.  The Allow-Headers issue is what got me.  But more than the code you posted, your explanation helped spark the light bulb to help me figure out how to get everything working.  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me :/ I just do it exactly this way in a servlet filter

Comment: @monsur, Btw exactly what is it about CORS that made you so interested about it to the extent that you wrote a book on it? (The one and only book on CORS in the [whole world](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=a9_asc_1?rh=i%3Astripbooks%2Ck%3ACORS&keywords=CORS&ie=UTF8&qid=1453787897).)

Comment: Shouldn't `OPTIONS` return a `204 No Content` response?

Comment: If your server is `Python` `Flask` app then you can just return `app.make_default_options_response()` on the `OPTIONS` method

Comment: As the question was about JQuery, you can have a look at the "contentType" option in https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings.
Extract : `Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.`

Comment: _any Content-Type other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` triggers the preflight._ Careful; this statement is incorrect and believing it to be true has [security ramifications](https://twitter.com/jub0bs/status/1432025054108430346).