# Annoying issue with CORS and Header Authentication with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my trouble:

With `$http` I'm trying to make a request. This is the response:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I just enable all that I need to make CORS request. This is on my server:

```
  httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
  httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, bbtoken, CUSTOM_AUTH_TOKEN, Authorization");
  httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "CUSTOM_AUTH_TOKEN");
```

This is the code from Angular:

```
 $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://www.myurl\:8080/mypath/myservice',
                    headers: {
                        CUSTOM_AUTH_TOKEN: SessionService.currentUser.token
                    }

                })
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            successCallback(data);
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.error(data);
                        });
```

But I found an infamous 401 Auth Error.

If I try with cURL or RestConsole (chrome), all is ok... **I cannot understand the mistake!**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the source request header

```
OPTIONS /mypath/blabla HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:8383
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom_auth_token
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8383/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: it
```

**UPDATE WITH RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Service"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1079
Date: Sun, 08 Jun 2014 08:08:32 GMT
```

Comment: You have to handle the OPTIONS request and send back the allow headers with empty response body (the easiest way to do that in a server config file). Btw you did not allow the content-type header. According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options any non basic html related content type such as json will cause a preflight.

Comment: You've edited this to show the OPTIONS request, now look at the response you are sending back for it.

Comment: The response seems indicate that the custom_auth_token is not passed... I'm not sure, but if you check the request, you cannot find : `custom_auth_token:'hextoken'` but `Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom_auth_token`. Is possible that this is the problem?

Comment: It is certainly a contributing factor. Why are you requiring authorization to determine what headers an XHR request is allowed to include in the first place?

Comment: CORS do not accept values inside OPTION method, but only the name of the headers. Your question is useful, in fact now, I'm checking spring security configuration. I think that happen a not standard HTTP behaviour  (OPTIONS with auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The problem came from by Spring Security. A nonsense configuration about security, needs authentication (by custom filter) on all request. OPTION included. By for HTTP standards, the headers inside the OPTION do not contain values, but only name (of the headers)

This is the solution for my trouble:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" method="OPTIONS" requires-channel="any"/>
```

Comment: hey, i am also facing the same issue, but could not resolve even after your solution. Could you please send the spring-security file contents?

Comment: I'm sorry , but I finished work on this project and I have no longer access to the code . But if you give me some more details , I can help you.

Comment: <security:http entry-point-ref="CSSCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  authentication-manager-ref="hybrid" pattern="/**" use-expressions="true"
  auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
  <security:custom-filter ref="userAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
   position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"
   method="OPTIONS" requires-channel="any" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
   access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
 </security:http>

Comment: I have above configuration, but my OPTIONS request is still getting authenticated. I am trying to not authenticate all requests with OPTIONS request.

Comment: I think with the following line <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" /> </security:http> your still close all of your http methods with Spring Security

Comment: Srikanth & Alexanoid - Could you please reply on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725249/cors-filter-issue-for-authentrypoint? Thnks, Neha

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a custom HTTP request header to the request, this prevents the request from being simple and makes it [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Before the browser will make the GET request, it will make an OPTIONS request to ask if the extra header is acceptable.

You need to set up your server so it will respond with suitable CORS headers to the OPTIONS request as well as the GET request.

Comment: About xxx_me_cookie it's a my mistake. I've updated the post: I changed my original values with other.

Comment: isn't enough? `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");`

Comment: Not if that's the code to set a header on the response to the GET request which is never made because the OPTIONS request doesn't get a suitable response.