# CORS Error on my domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cpanel, sabre

I had been developing a website and had disabled web security to bypass CORS through the following command

chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo

After successfully developing the website, I uploaded it to my domain but got stuck with the CORS Error. I have tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", but had no luck.

I can assume CORS error for localhost, but cannot understand why the error persists in my domain?

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx-xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: In which language you build  your web service.On the server will need to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: I do not have access to the server. I am calling the web service via ajax request. I have set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the header of the request but no success

Comment: I face the same problem recently there  you may set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on web service.Or you may user nginx for deployment .

This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320736/5621827

Comment: I compiled the same code under ionic framework and deployed that as an android app and there seems to be no problem there. Working on the domain, it generates this error. I have included all possible headers for CORS but still no luck. Will keep looking though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS your server has to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE" (for example).

For a quick reference you can check the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or for an in depth info visit de [w3c specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: I do not have access to the server. It is a third party web service

Comment: @I.Qureshi — You can't give yourself permission to access data a third party is sending to a visitor's browser. That would be a terrible security problem.

Comment: I have the access to communicate with them. I've already mailed them the issue and am waiting for their response. The only issue is of CORS

Answer (score 0):

The third part webService must be allowed you access or they had done CORS for every origins. So you just communicate with them. Hope it can help you.