# CORS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors, access-control

I'm trying to login to moodle from an external webpage using a post form to moodle, I used the next ajax to send the inputs:

```
var frm = $('#loginForm');

frm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        xhrFields:{
            withCredentials:true
        },
        async:true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Logged");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("NOT Logged");
        },
    });
});
```

Now into the moodle's login/index.php I insert the headers to make possible the CORS connection:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://fabianmurillo.000webhostapp.com");
header("Origin" : "http://fabianmurillo.000webhostapp.com");
```

When I run the code, the browser returns an error:

```
..preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc0t0.png)

Dunno why browser is blocking the connection for login to moodle.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header.
You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery CORS Content-type OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options)

Comment: @Koresh What do you mean with Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header? So what header should I use? can you help me?

Comment: I invite you to take a look to the question and more specifically the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options
It contains information about how CORS works and interresting links. This should greatly help you.