# Convert recursive POST data to JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, forms, post

I'm `POST`ing JSON via javascript to an endpoint as form data, not in the body.  I'm doing this to avoid an extra CORS `OPTIONS` lookup.  The JSON is formatted as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somewhere',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "foo": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        "bar": [
            {
                "biz": [
                    "c",
                    "d"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // something
    }
});
```

When the query string comes through, it looks like `foo%5B%5D=a&foo%5B%5D=b&bar%5B0%5D%5Bbiz%5D%5B%5D=c&bar%5B0%5D%5Bbiz%5D%5B%5D=d`

I parse the query string with:

```
data = parse.unquote(data)
data = parse.parse_qs(data)
print(json.dumps(data))
```

But the resulting dict/json is

```
{
  "foo[]": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "bar[0][biz][]": [
    "c",
    "d"
  ]
}
```

This is problematic since I can't traverse the original keys.  How can I convert the received value back into it's original JSON form?

---

This is what I have so far

```
def findValue(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        value = findValue(list(value.keys())[0])
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        value = findValue(value[0])
    return prepareValue(value)

def prepareKey(data, value=None):
    print(data)
    if isinstance(data, str):
        match = re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\[([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\](.*)', data)
        return match[0]
    if data[2] != '':
        additional = prepareKey(data[2], value)
    else:
        additional = value
    return {data[0]: {data[1]: additional}}

def prepareValue(value):
    if len(value) == 1:
        value = value[0]
    return value

def preparePost(data, newData=False):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if not newData:
            newData = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            match = re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\[([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\](.*)', key)
            if len(match):
                assignment = findValue(value)
                thisData = prepareKey(match[0], assignment)
                newData.update(thisData)
            else:
                newData[key] = prepareValue(value)
    return newData

data = parse.unquote(data)
data = parse.parse_qs(data)
data = preparePost(data)
print(data)
```

It works moderately well but fails on the deeply nested values.

This is the real query I'm working with: `foo=bar&cart%5Bcurrency%5D=USD&cart%5Banalytics%5D%5Blib%5D%5Bintegrations%5D%5B0%5D%5Boptions%5D%5BdefaultAttributes%5D%5BthemeId%5D=38654869555&cart%5Banalytics%5D%5Blib%5D%5Bintegrations%5D%5B0%5D%5Boptions%5D%5BdefaultAttributes%5D%5BcontentLanguage%5D=en`

I can get as far as `{'foo': 'bar', 'cart': {'currency': 'USD'}}` but it fails on `cart%5Banalytics%5D%5Blib%5D%5Bintegrations%5D%5B0%5D%5Boptions%5D%5BdefaultAttributes%5D%5BthemeId%5D=38654869555`

---

## Solution

Stringify the JSON and send the correct headers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somewhere',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "foo": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        "bar": [
            {
                "biz": [
                    "c",
                    "d"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }),
    success: function(response) {
        // something
    }
});
```

Comment: `foo%5B%5D=a&foo%5B%5D=b&bar%5B0%5D%5Bbiz%5D%5B%5D=c&bar%5B0%5D%5Bbiz%5D%5B%5D=d` is not valid urlencoded param. Are you sure that it's correct?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Pretty sure.  It seems to be working here: http://icyberchef.com/#recipe=URL_Decode()&input=Zm9vJTVCJTVEPWEmZm9vJTVCJTVEPWImYmFyJTVCMCU1RCU1QmJpeiU1RCU1QiU1RD1jJmJhciU1QjAlNUQlNUJiaXolNUQlNUIlNUQ9ZA

Comment: Why just to not use  `application/json` in `Content-Type`?

Comment: And it's not correct urlencoded string. If you've decided to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, than you need to send pairs param_name=param_value. Correct pair will be `json=foo[]%3Da%26foo[]%3Db%26bar[0][biz][]%3Dc%26bar[0][biz][]%3Dd`

Comment: Because then an `OPTIONS` pre-flight is sent for CORS, then the `POST`.  This means twice the response time.  This answer explains when CORS is required https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320736/763468

Comment: Why not send it as one JSON encoded value, i.e. `data: { json: JSON.stringify({ foo: [...] }) }` and then parse the single `json` value on the server side?

Comment: Yep.  Thanks working.  Not sure how I missed that.  Thanks all