# Angular.JS unsuccessfully tries to load a view with the OPTIONS HTTP method

Tags: http, model-view-controller, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have been following along with the **AngularJS Fundamentals In 60-ish Minutes** tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

I was doing fine until I got 52 minutes in when the tutor tests out the app. At this point in the app we are trying to load a view. When I tried to load my app I saw nothing in my window. I opened up Chrome Dev Tools > Network and saw that status for `View1.html`, which is the view that was supposed to be loaded in, was `Load Cancelled`. I also noticed that Angular tried to call it via the `OPTIONS` method. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In my attempt to solve this issue I came across this SO question

[AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource/12112294)

and the similarity to my problem was that Angular was using OPTIONS to retrieve data. The difference was that in that case, Angular was retrieving a cross-origin resource. So that makes sense but not in my case. All I was trying to do was load a view which was located on my system. Here is the directory structure of my `AngularApp` folder located on my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop:

```
.
├── app.html
├── Partials
│   ├── View1.html
│   └── View2.html
└── scripts
    └── angular.js
```

The URL I use to view my app is

`file:///home/max/Desktop/AngularApp/app.html`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is the `app.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
  <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>                                      
  <div>
    <!-- Placeholder for views -->
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
              })
        .when('/view2',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
              })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
    });


    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Hasbro Meclan', city: 'New South Rolly' },
        { name: 'Haley Meclan', city: 'New South Rolly' },
        { name: 'Sammy Watson', city: 'New South Rolly' },
        { name: 'Sammy Warboy', city: 'Onice City' }
      ];

      $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
          { 
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
      };

    });  
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is View1.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>View 1</h2>
  Name:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:city">
  </ul>
  <br/>
  Customer Name:<br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
  <br/>
  Customer City:<br/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
  <br/>
  <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
  <br/>
  <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an angularJS problem, but a CORS problem - loading resources from your computer is considered "cross-origin-like", as there is no server (namely, he browser's origin is probably "null"). As marcoseu said, using a server is the way to go - python and node.js have very simple implementations, but what I would recommend is that you try yeoman (http://www.yeoman.io). It is an integrated workflow solution for building js webapps, and plays specially well with angularJS. (I think the main page in yeoman's site has angularJS as an example)

**Edit after comment**

I vouch for yeoman as I use it for all my projects - as some of the developers in the angularJS team are actively working on the yeoman generators, it has a lot of acceptance, and necessarily follows all of angular's standard practices. But it should be noted that yeoman does much more than just serve as a local http server. It controls scaffolding, testing (as in test-driven development, not just viewing files in a local server), and building the app (minifying and concatenating, handle dependencies, and so on...)

It is very complete and, as such, can be rather complicated (specially when you have specific requirements for the build tasks). But if you intend to deploy one or several angularJS apps, it can be a tremendous help!

Comment: Yes - Yeoman scaffolds the projects (using the structure in angular-seed, which is "the standard"), simplifies dependencies on other js apps/plugins/frameworks, and terribly simplifies testing (meaning seeing preliminar results, via a js server). Also, it is great for working with sass-lang, which I use.

Comment: nice, yes i use Sass too. I have installed it and will start to grok it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often have weird problem with running AngularJS code going through file://.  Assuming you have python, you can try to launch a simple webserver at the root directory of the app using:

```
cd /home/max/Desktop/AngularApp/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: Whenever I need a quick and dirty web server, yes.  In fact, I create an alias called webserver for it so I don't have to remember the syntax.