# How to read binary data in AngularJS in an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS there is the [`$http.get`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#get) to dynamically fetch data. Unfortunately, from the official doc is not easy to understand how to read binary data (for example, for image manipulation).

The default `get` fetches the data as a `String` ([see it in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RPMSuSN7k4pu60GISHbQ?p=preview)). This is [very cumbersome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-bin-data). So, how to get it in an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer)? (Note that since XHR2 this is [already possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using $http.get to read binary data</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <h1>$http to load binary data</h1>
    <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl" >
      <button ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button><br/>
      {{info}}
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Controller
    function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {
      // See note 1
      $scope.URL = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png";
      $scope.info = "Click 'fetch' to fetch an image" ;

      $scope.fetch = function() {
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']; // See note 2
        $http.get($scope.URL).
          success(function(data) {
            $scope.info = "Read '" + $scope.URL + "' with " + data.length
            + " chars in a variable of type '" + typeof(data) + "'";
          }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = "Request failed with status: " + status;
          });
      };
    }      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Note 1:* The size of the original file is 473.831 bytes.
*Note 2:* If the image to fetch belongs to a different domain, resetting headers could be necessary to perform a [simple cross-site request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests): By default, `AngularJS 1.0.6` sets the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, forcing a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), that is, the browser sends an http `OPTIONS` request before the `GET`. This could be not supported by the server (like in this example, where the server returns a `403 HTTP method not allowed`). 
[This header was removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1004) six months ago though, (that is, from `AngularJS 1.1.1` on), and the reset is not necessary anymore  (thanks by the way to [this answer to *AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15306568/413020)).

Answer (score 54):

Fortunately, [Vojta Jina](https://github.com/vojtajina) has already implemented [this feature](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1013%20%22%22) in [branch 1.1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e0a54f6b206dc2b6595f2bc3a17c5932e7477545). The following code ([see it in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VamSRwYDIuHs8KEJvxG8?p=preview)) fetches the binary data in an `ArrayBuffer`. Note the use of the (as for today) still unstable `AngularJS 1.1.5`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using $http.get to read binary data</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Using $http.get to read binary data</h1>
    <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl" >
      <button ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button><br/>
      {{info}}
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Controller
    function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {
      // See note 1
      $scope.URL = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png";
      $scope.info = "Click 'fetch' to fetch an image" ;
      $scope.fetch = function() {
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']; // See note 2
        $http.get($scope.URL, {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).
          success(function(data) {
            $scope.info = "Read '" + $scope.URL + "' with " + data.byteLength
            + " bytes in a variable of type '" + typeof(data) + "'";
          }).
          error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.info = "Request failed with status: " + status;
          });
      };
    }      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Note 1 and note 2:* see notes in the original question.

Comment: Does this work in Angular 1.2? I try (in Chrome) and get a string instead of the ArrayBuffer

Comment: I wish I would've found this before spending so much time wondering how to handle the data got from CDN..

Comment: Old, but does the job. Thanks.

Comment: "Request failed with status undefined" ?

Comment: {responseType: "arraybuffer"}  simple but works perfectly! My hero

Comment: Life saver!  in Angular 2+, it should be `{ responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer}`