# Some of characters gets changed when i open my file in older version of wordpad

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, file-writing

I have a java script code which writes the file in UTF-8 encoding and because of that some characters gets changed when this file opens in Wordpad(Older vesion) 
like ééééèèèààà(in UTF-8) changed to Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã¨Ã¨Ã¨Ã Ã Ã (in ANSI / older version of wordpad).

```
var filename = document.getElementById('my_label').innerHTML;
    filename = filename.replace(/.pdf,".txt");
    filename = filename.trim();
    var blob = new Blob([textout], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, filename);
```

The characters should be same everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "\ufeff" at the beginning fixed the issue.

```
var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff",textout]
```

Same solution for this problem also. Found solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925210/download-blob-content-using-specified-charset/18925211)