# Angular $http get binary data from png

Tags: angularjs

I want to read this png in binary format.

I have been reading all over the net, and this looks like the correct way of doing it with angular.

**But it just does not work. Any idea why?**

```
 $http({
                url: 'somepng.png',
                method: 'GET',
                data: '',
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }).success(function(resp, config1, config2, config3) {
                console.log(typeof resp); // this is a string, weird! in Chrome
                console.log(resp);
            });
```

The arrray buffer returns a string instead of an array o of bytes.

Comment: Try to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791295/how-to-read-binary-data-in-angularjs-in-an-arraybuffer

Comment: Whisher, this uses the example exactly like in the post you gave me.

Comment: Adding the `responseType: "arraybuffer"` to the config worked for me, as proposed in the answer linked to by @Whisher.

Answer (score 1):

```
var config = {headers: {
            'Accept': "image/png"
        }
    };
$http.get('somepng.png', config).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
```

this answer is the changed one....

Comment: I am not doing post request

Comment: That didn't change anything for me and it doesn't seem logical why it should.