# arrayBuffer AngularJs POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, blob

I've got a POST request like this:

```
 $scope.myFunction = function (name, id, value) {
      $http.post(/retrievePDFFiles, {
                    name: name,
                    id: id,
                    value: value
                }).success(function(data, headers) {
                    var filename = headers('filename');
                    if(data.byteLength > 250) {
                        var blob = new Blob([data], {type : 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8'});
                        saveAs(blob, filename);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }

                }).error(function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                });
}
```

With this call i send some parameters to save them in a table in my db and as response i have a pdf stream. The request to the server it returns correctly 200 and all parameters are corrected and everything is saved in db but the pdf not works. I've got an error in console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

and if i debug the request it goes in the .error function. I think the problem is that it doesn't recognize that it needs to download a stream and, i don't know, it doesn't work. I think just adding

```
responseType : 'arraybuffer'
```

somewhere it will works but i don't know where! I can't touch the structure of the parameters.. Any idea?

EDIT: i tried as written here with no results
[How to read binary data in AngularJS in an ArrayBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791295/how-to-read-binary-data-in-angularjs-in-an-arraybuffer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read binary data in AngularJS in an ArrayBuffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791295/how-to-read-binary-data-in-angularjs-in-an-arraybuffer)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, i've already tried that way with no success

Comment: You passed the config properties as the third argument? get, and post use different number of arguments, get has the the config options as the second argument while post uses it as the third argument

Comment: You mean in the success?

Comment: No, in the post call `$http.post(url,data,{responseType:"arraybuffer"})`

Comment: So, what you're meaning it's put all parameters in a data array and use your structure? I try

Comment: No, im saying add the config options to your call as a third argument, `$http.post("/retrievePDFFiles",{name:name,id:id},{responseType:"arraybuffer"})`

Comment: I'm trying.. let me some minute

Comment: man seems it's working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.factory('apiService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        downloadFile: function(url, file) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: file,
                responseType: 'arrayBuffer'
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.download = function(name, id, value) {
    //form the payload for file download
    var payload = {
        name: name,
        id: id,
        value: value
    };

    //execute service to download
    apiService.downloadFile('/retrievePdfFiles', payload).then(function(response) {
        //download the blob
        var contentType = response.headers()['content-type'] || octetStreamMime;
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], contentType);
    }).catch(function(response){
        //there's been an error
    });
}
```