# Angular $http.post not sending any data

Tags: javascript, json, post, angularjs

I'm super stuck with trying to simply post JSON data but for some reason it won't work.

```
angular.module('pocket.controllers', [])
  .controller('ArticleList', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.signIn = function() {

      var postObject = new Object();
      postObject.consumer_key = pocketKey;
      postObject.redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com";

      $http.post(apiUrl, postObject).success(function(data){
        alert(data);
      });
    }

  })
```

When I inspect the request in the Chrome inspector it doesn't seem like any data is actually being posted:

```
Request URL:https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:getpocket.com
Origin:http://pocket.dev:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://pocket.dev:8000/app/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 24 Jul 2013 17:18:04 GMT
P3P:policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE"
Server:Apache/2.2.25 (Amazon)
Status:400 Bad Request
X-Error:Missing consumer key.
X-Error-Code:138
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.27
X-Source:Pocket
```

As you can see, the X-Error is "Missing consumer key" which implies the data is not being posted correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code;

> $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Modified code will be like this;

> angular.module('pocket.controllers', [])   .controller('ArticleList',
>   function($scope, $http) {
>
> ```
> $scope.signIn = function() {
>
>   var postObject = new Object();
>   postObject.consumer_key = pocketKey;
>   postObject.redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com";
>   $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
>   $http.post(apiUrl, postObject).success(function(data){
>     alert(data);
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> })

Comment: That doesn't work either, I think it has something do with their server not supporting CORS and thus not being able todo cross-origin POST requests.

Comment: Are you doing this in a single domain or are you having cross domain POST request?

Comment: No, this is a cross-domain request to the Pocket API: http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication