# AngularJS - $http get returns error with status 0?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, cors, http-get

I've an AngularJS application in which I'm trying to get an XML data with $http get from a server say http://example.com/a/b/c/d/getDetails?fname=abc&lname=def (this when accessed manually by entering the link in a browser shows a tree structure of the XML file).

When I run the application the data from that link is not fetched. Instead its showing an error with **status 0**.

```
//url = http://example.com/a/b/c/d/getDetails?fname=abc&lname=def
$http.get(url).success(function (data){
                alert("Success");
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status){
                console.log("Error status : " + status);
            });
```

I'm not sure why the $http.get fails and goes to the error function returning status 0.

But if I pass an URL to the local server which has a JSON object, it works.

Is the problem because of me trying to access the XML file from a different domain(CORS issue?) or something else?

Please help me out!

Comment: Yes, See your console, you should have got an error (Cross Origin ...)

Comment: Nope. I haven't got anything like that in my console.

Comment: What if I don't want to console log the error but return it to the DOM?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issues .

The server answering your REST requests MUST include the headers specified by CORS in order to allow Angular to consume properly the response. Essentially this means including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your response, specifying the servers from where the request comes from, that are allowed. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021971/3069430))

There is directive [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider) allows one to get/set the whitelists and blacklists used to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing Angular templates are safe.

Comment: So will it be enough if I whitelist the link I use to access the XML data?

Comment: If you use xmlhttprequests you need JSONpadding.

However, the server must supports "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)" in this can it's quiet simple to receive data from a other domain.

Answer (score 2):

yes you got it right, its because default content-type for $http is  “application/json” if you want to change the request data or response data you can change it with the help of tranformRequest and tranformResponse. you can find more information on it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

also i find an article on implementation of tranformRequest [change post data from json to form post in angularjs](http://blog.yiiframe.com/angularjs/angularjs-simple-form-post-example-with-php/)

Comment: Thanks. So for my application after using transformRequest, should I use xml2json to convert the xml content to JSON and use it? (http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/) or is there any other better solution to this?

Comment: your link is redirecting to spam sites