# Angular/Ionic handling successful 200 as an error

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I'm using ionic with a google cloud function and when I return data to my application angular defaults to handling it as an error.

Here's my cloud function call back using node:
I have already tried adding curly braces to payload and but it didn't help.

```
function (error, response, body) {
    let payload = parser.toJson(body, parserOptions);
    console.log(payload)
    res.status(200).send(payload);
}
```

In the console logs for that call back I get:

```
{ 
    ResponseCode: '0',
    referenceID: '22072017152436718488608295',
    ResponseMessage: 'SUCCESS',
    paymentURL: 'url',
    net_amount: '0',
    invoiceNumber: '0',
    status: '200' 
}
```

Which is the data I expect to receive in my Angular/Ionic code.
Testing this in Postman works too.

Angular Code:

```
return this.http.post('/api', body, headers)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('Success')
            console.log(data)
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error')
            console.log(err.status)
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    )
```

I get an error status of 0 and error message of null.

Comment: could you subscribe to the request directly (i.e. remove the `.map`) and see if that gives you some more information - it could be that it is failing to parse the response for some reason

Comment: @0mpurdy Just tried, still getting the same error without the .map

Comment: can you do `console.log(err)` and get any more information?

Comment: @0mpurdy Simply an error object with code 0 and message null.

Comment: Ok I think it is answered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149703/6894075) it's for angularjs but it is probably still a CORS error, hopefully that's enough for you to sort your problem! An angular 2 related question would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36768418/6894075)

Comment: You're right @0mpurdy, adding a header to my node response worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a CORS error described [similarly here for angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149703/6894075) and with more explanation in [this answer for Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36768418/6894075)

The solution is adding a header server side to handle CORS.