# Is there a way to avoid Preflighting with $http?

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, angularjs-service

I'm using nginx on the remote server, and with no support for the `OPTIONS` method I've been terribly stuck. Both the server and angular refuse to talk to each other.

I just want to make a simple $http.post() request. Is there a way to configure the service to ONLY send the POST request, and not do any preflighting with OPTIONS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something AngularJS does, but something your browser does according to the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard. [See also this answer on a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12112294/2670336).

However, if you make it so that the AngularJS application is served from the same domain as your resource (different subdomains will affect cross-origin), then the browser will not send the OPTIONS request as the resource is no longer from a cross-origin server.

Example:

- www.example.com requests resource on api.example.com will trigger OPTIONS request
- www.example.com requests resource from www.example.com/api will **not** trigger OPTIONS request

Comment: Cross Origin is just unavoidable in my current situation :( Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1):

If CORS is Unavoidable 
You could change the header of the request to text/plain and then parse your response manually acording to answers in this link below

[How to skip the OPTIONS preflight request in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs)