# How to skip the OPTIONS preflight request?

Tags: angularjs, post, cors, preflight

I had developed a PhoneGap app which is now being transformed to a mobile website. Everything works smoothly besides one small glitch. I use a certain third party API via a POST request, which works fine in the app, but fails in the mobile website version.

After a closer look it seems like AngularJS (I guess the browser actually) is first sending an OPTIONS request. I learned a lot today about CORS, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable it altogether. I do not have access to that API (so changes at that side are impossible), but they have added the domain I am working on to their Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

This is the code I am talking about:

```
        var request = {
                language: 'fr',
                barcodes: [
                    {
                        barcode: 'somebarcode',
                        description: 'Description goes here'
                    }
                ]
            };
        }
        var config = {
            headers: { 
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        $http.post('http://somedomain.be/trackinginfo', request, config).success(function(data, status) {
            callback(undefined, data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            var err = new Error('Error message');
            err.status = status;
            callback(err);
        });
```

How can I prevent the browser (or AngularJS) from sending that OPTIONS request and just skip to the actual POST request? I am using AngularJS 1.2.0.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The preflight is being triggered by your Content-Type of `application/json`.  The simplest way to prevent this is to set the Content-Type to be `text/plain` in your case. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` & `multipart/form-data` Content-Types are also acceptable, but you'll of course need to format your request payload appropriately.

If you are still seeing a preflight after making this change, then Angular may be adding an X-header to the request as well.

Or you might have headers (Authorization, Cache-Control...) that will trigger it, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: This is the correct answer--your Content-Type and Cache-Control headers are triggering a preflight request. A plain GET with a Content-Type of text/plain and a few others are the only ways to trigger a non-preflighted request. See:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about Cache-Control.

Comment: A custom header will also trigger the preflight.

Comment: Changing the content type to prevent the OPTIONs test is not the answer. The content type should match the content type regardless

Comment: if it is browser throwing, & in the backend, Http method OPTIONS is blocked, will it have any effect like the browser will be not calling the corresponding API for POST/ PUT as OPTIONS failed?

Answer (score 16):

As what Ray said, you can stop it by modifying content-header like -

```
 $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";
```

For Example -

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('User', ['$resource','$http',
    function($resource,$http){
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";
        return $resource(API_ENGINE_URL+'user/:userId', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{userId:'users'}, isArray:true},
            getLoggedIn:{method:'GET'}
        });
    }]);
```

Or directly to a call -

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

This will not send any pre-flight option request.

**NOTE:** Request should not have any custom header parameter, If request header contains any custom header then browser will make pre-flight request, you cant avoid it.

Comment: How should I do it just with `$http`?

Comment: Thanks, that's similar of what I was doing. The only changes are the method `GET` and an extra header `Authorization`. But still sending the preflight.

Comment: Can you paste your request here ? as curl or something?  Maybe its because of Authorization header, try to remove it and then try. If you are sending custom headers then angular will send pre-flight request.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vRDeFiH2 The first is the request to $http and the second is a valid request build it by postman :)

Answer (score 5):

When performing certain types of cross-domain AJAX requests, modern browsers that support CORS will insert an extra "preflight" request to determine whether they have permission to perform the action.
From example query:

```
$http.get( ‘https://example.com/api/v1/users/’ +userId,
  {params:{
           apiKey:’34d1e55e4b02e56a67b0b66’
          }
  } 
);
```

As a result of this fragment we can see that the address was sent two requests (OPTIONS and GET). The response from the server includes headers confirming the permissibility the query GET. If your server is not configured to process an OPTIONS request properly, client requests will fail. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 172800
Allow: PUT
Allow: OPTIONS
Allow: POST
Allow: DELETE
Allow: GET
```

Answer (score 2):

I think best way is check if request is of type "OPTIONS" return 200 from middle ware. It worked for me.

```
express.use('*',(req,res,next) =>{
      if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
        res.status(200);
        res.send();
      }else{
        next();
      }
    });
```

Comment: It works but in OWASP it is recommended not to expose OPTIONS. You weather block it in backend/ hosted service(Nginx, Apache) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Preflight is a web security feature implemented by the browser. For Chrome you can disable all web security by adding the --disable-web-security flag.

For example: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\newChromeSettingsWithoutSecurity" . You can first create a new shortcut of chrome, go to its properties and change the target as above. This should help!

Comment: You can't really expect OP to tell his clients to turn off browser security just to enable a feature, right?!

Comment: @svarog this is mostly for dev purposes, mostly on production server you won't face this issue.

Comment: if it is browser throwing, & in the backend, Http method OPTIONS is blocked, will it have any effect like the browser will be not calling the corresponding API for POST/ PUT as OPTIONS failed?

Answer (score -3):

setting the content-type to undefined would make javascript pass the header data As it is , and over writing the default angular $httpProvider header configurations. [Angular $http Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http({url:url,method:"POST", headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}).then(success,failure);
```