# AngularJS POST fails with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when using data payload object but works using query params like payload

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I am facing a weird issue. I am running my angularjs app in nodejs server locally which calls a POST API from my app located on Google App Engine. The API is configured with all CORS headers required as follows:

```
def post(self):
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, content-type, accept, myapp-domain")
self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = “application/json; charset=utf-8”
```

GET requests to the API work without issues.

POST requests to the API work but **ONLY** when I send the post data as a 'string of params' and **NOT** when post data is sent as an object which is the right way to do. Eventually I need to be able to upload pictures using this API so the first solution below might not work for me. Please help!

**METHOD 1: This works:**

```
postMessageAPI = "https://myapp-qa.appspot.com/message";

var postData = "conversationid=1c34b4f2&userid=67e80bf6&content='Hello champs! - Web App'";

var postConfig = {
    headers:  {
    "MYAPP-DOMAIN" : "myapp.bz",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
};

$http.post(postMessageAPI, postData, postConfig).
success(function(data){
     $log.log("POST Message API success");
}).
error(function(data, status) {
    $log.error("POST Message API FAILED. Status: "+status);
    $log.error(JSON.stringify(postData));
});
```

**METHOD 2: This fails:**

```
postMessageAPI = "https://myapp-qa.appspot.com/message";

var postData = ({
    'conversationid' : '1c34b4f2',
    'userid' : '67e80bf6',
    'content' : 'Hello champs! - Web App'
});

var postConfig = {
    headers:  {
    "MYAPP-DOMAIN" : "myapp.bz"
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
};

$http.post(postMessageAPI, postData, postConfig).
success(function(data){
     $log.log("POST Message API success");
}).
error(function(data, status) {
    $log.error("POST Message API FAILED. Status: "+status);
    $log.error(JSON.stringify(postData));
});
```

When I use **METHOD 2** it fails with the following error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapp-qa.appspot.com/message. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with Angular sending a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request to check the access headers from the server. I am not sure how `OPTIONS` requests are handled in your API, but I am betting these headers are not being added. I suggest installing [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the actual requests to see what is going on with the headers. You may only be adding them to your `POST` responses.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs) answer for details on why **METHOD 1** may work in this scenario, while **METHOD 2** does not.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) are some more details about pre-flight requests.