# Angularjs $http.post() is sending an OPTIONS request only

Tags: angularjs, post, http-post

I've got some Angular code where I am attempting to send a POST to a dev server.

```
var url = 'http://someDevUrl.com',
    data = { 'someKey': 'some value' };
$http.post(url, data);
```

It sends the OPTIONS preflight request.  I can see it hit the server, and the server gives it a happy response.

OPTIONS Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 18:20:44 GMT
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 30
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

but then Angular never sends the POST after that...

Typically when $http.post() only sends an OPTIONS request, that means the OPTIONS request returned an error (usually a CORS issue).  But in this case, all is fine with the OPTIONS request & response, but it still won't send the POST.

Has anyone seen this before or have an idea of what might be preventing it from sending the POST?

***EDIT:***
I've got around the issue by adding a `Content-Type: text/plain` header to the request:

```
var url = 'http://someDevUrl.com',
    data = { 'someKey': 'some value' },
    config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }
   }
};
$http.post(url, data, config);
```

which [causes it to skip the OPTIONS preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs#answer-22968724), thus avoiding the issue.  I'm still curious to know why it was not working in the first place, since there was/is no CORS issue and the OPTIONS request was not sending back an error response.

Comment: I'm going to bet that you need to go ahead and at minimum, define your .success(d,s,h,c) callback. See if that doesn't cause the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually do have a success() callback defined in the actual code, but I excluded it from the example code, above, as it didn't seem relevant to the question.  The success/then callback isn't used/relevant until after the POST is sent, so it doesn't make a difference when I include/exclude it since it never gets to the point of sending the POST.

Comment: I ran a test on my end against one of my APIs to verify your response... One line that concerns me is this:
Connection:keep-alive // this is what I get back, yours says close...

So my next place would be to look and see if you could prevent the API from sending back a close response.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs/36086583#36086583/) on similar question