# Every time I post data using angular to asp.net webapi I see a pre flight call http options is made how to stop it

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I am bit new to angular I am trying to do a http post for my login button for sending data to asp.net webapi application. But every time I see there is a pre flight check done with a call http options . I am read some articles mention option verb comes only if its other than get or post.

But not sure why I am getting this for http post.
Any idea why? Howbit could be stopped?

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This happens typically for a cross domain request being made. You website is on different url\port than your webapi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip the OPTIONS preflight request in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs)