# CORS, prevent preflight of request with Authorization header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

AngularJS transforms my `POST` request into `OPTIONS` when I add `Authorization` header:

```
  $http({
    url: ApiEndpoint + 'logout',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': UserService.getApiKey()
    }
  })
```

I'm developpling a hybrid mobile application with Ionic that I test in browser, os it's a CORS request.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs) question. The proposed workaround is to change  `Content-Type` that I did and it worked without `Authorization`. With `Authorization` header the request is changed again to OPTIONS method.

Can you propose client solution please because a have no control over server API.

Thank you.

Comment: Preflight will be triggered in your case as setting 'Authorization' header will make your request *not simple* in MDN terms. The only allowed headers to be set manually to classify as *simple* are Accept,
Accept-Language, Content-Language and Content-Type.  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS .Not sure whether you could avoid pre-flight, but you could cache it for a given time frame for requests.

Answer (score 7):

As others have noted, what you are seeing are CORS preflight requests.

You can't avoid them if you want to set `Authorization` header, but there are some workarounds if you control the backend (or are willing to use proxy). More info: https://damon.ghost.io/killing-cors-preflight-requests-on-a-react-spa/

In short:

- CORS preflight headers can be cached by browser (set [Access-Control-Max-Age header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) to number of seconds the response should be cached)
- authorization header can be moved to URL params (if this is a good idea or not is a whole other discussion)
- you can send JSON without proper headers (again, not the best of ideas, but...)
- if it fits your use case, the simplest solution is to use proxy and thus avoid *cross-origin* requests completely

Comment: "CORS preflight headers can be cached" -- it would be nice if you added some explanation about how that is done.

Comment: Sure, done. (and I need to add some bogus text here so that this comment is at least 15 chars long)

Answer (score 6):

as [Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5665484/developer) remarked, the CORS request will be preflighted unless it is a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score -2):

To avoid preflight request, Just create your own controller and then, From the server code call the other origin REST service.

```html
<pre>

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws IOException {
  String outputString = request.getParameter("data");  /*Refer the ajax data $.ajax({
         url:"callRestApi",
         type:'POST',
         data: { 
    "data":"data Value"
   },
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(uname + ":" + passwd));
         },
         success:function(){
          alert("Successfully created JSON data from DB");
         },
         error:function(textStatus, jqXHR){
          alert("Unable to process some of the types, Please check logs for details.");
         }
     });*/
  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
  URL url = new URL("");// just example, in your case pass the URL here
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "");// just example, in your
             // case pass the content
             // type here
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "");// just example, in your
              // case pass the
              // authorization key
              // here
  DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
    conn.getOutputStream());
  outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  if (conn != null && conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
   int bytesRead;
   InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
   while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8"));
    buffer = new byte[8192];
    bytesRead = 0;
   }
  }
  System.out.println("Output ===>" + sb.toString());
 }
</pre>
```

In the above example there will not be any preflight Request. because of the Rest API call will be done in server side.

Comment: This will not work if the server cannot access the other server.