# Difference betwen html post and js http.post

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://serviceURL/">
  <input name="account"  ng-value="form.account" type="hidden">
  <input name="name"     ng-value="form.name" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form all goes perfect. But when I try to do the same post request inside an angular service I'm getting

> cannot load https://serviceURL/  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 504

my service function looks like this

```
service.callServer =function(){
    var query = "https://serviceURL/";      
    $http.post(query,{account:123,name:'jhon'});

}
```

My question is: What is the difference betwen those types of request? does the html action post add some headers that the http.post doesn't?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Ajax requests cannot be submitted to domains other than the one you're on, unless the server sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header specifying your domain. To validate that, a browser first sends `preflight` OPTIONS request, and it seems that your server responds with an error to that request. This doesn't apply to submitting html forms, since it's not AJAX request.

Comment: Your answer is pretty clear to me,  I appreciate your time