# REST API call in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, http-status-code-406

Im having trouble making REST API calls in my ionic app to my server. It shows the following error.

**ionic.bundle.js:25005 OPTIONS https://website.com/api/ionic_test 406 (Not Acceptable)**

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://website.com/api/ionic_test. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 406**

API call code.

```
$http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/ionic_test', user).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.data.status) {
                        storeUserCredentials(result.data.token);
                        resolve(result.data.msg);
                    } else {
                        reject(result.data.msg);
                    }
                });
```

ionic.config.json

```
{
  "name": "adminPanel",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://website.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: look up CORS, there are quite a few questions and answers to this already.

Comment: in fact, 2,817 questions with `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present ` "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present"

Comment: @Claies I have gone through many similar questions. enabling CORS gives me this error. question has been edited

Comment: this seems like a server issue, not an ionic issue... what kind of server is this? what do the routes look like?  also, the error is showing `https://`;  does it still give the same error with `http://`?

Comment: @Claies When I take the url in browser im getting the response. But not in the ionic app. Do you want the complete api url?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your server. In the comments you said the API works in browser, but not in your app. That's because your browser doesn't send an `OPTIONS` "preflight" request, which Ionic does.

You need to either [disable the preflight request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs), or configure your server to handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use these in your app config to resolve the preflight issue

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

Eg.

```js
angular.module('yourApp', [])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //To solve Response for preflight has invalid HTTP 
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};


    //--------------------------------------

    // your routes here
});
```