# How to discard preflight response in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cors

When sending a http.post request to my service I initially send an Option request (as required by Cors).

However I've realized that my **OPTIONS** (pre-flight) request is returning no `response.data` in its response, but my **POST** request is. This poses a problem as I need to access the `response.data` from the **POST** response...

Does Angular allow us to somehow discard the OPTIONS response in a `http.post` call?

```
$http.post("http://api.worksiteclouddev.com/RestfulAPI/api/vw_PeopleListSiteAccess_Update/Get/", JSON.stringify(vm.content))
    .then(function (response) {
        //success

        vm.person = {
            "firstname": response.data.Firstname,
            "surname": response.data.surname
        }; 
        console.log(response.data);
    },
    function (error) {
        //failure
        console.log("Something went wrong..." + error.status);
    })
    .finally(function () {
        vm.ptsnumber = "";
    });
```

Chrome responses:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You state: "but my POST request is...I need to access the response.data from the POST response." - It doesn't make sense.

Comment: The questions is exactly as I describe it to be. I'm receiving two responses, one for the **OPTIONS** request and one for the **POST** request. The **OPTIONS** request seems to be returned before the **POST**, even though I'm only sending a **POST** request to the service.

How can I discard the **OPTIONS** response?

Comment: @geostocker Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't discard preflight OPTIONS request.

The purpose of this request is to ask the server for permissions to make the actual request. Your preflight response needs to acknowledge these headers in order for the actual request to work.

They are necessary when you're making requests across different origins.

This pre-flight request is made by some browsers as a safety measure to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server. Meaning the server understands that the method, origin and headers being sent on the request are safe to act upon.

In your case you should get the response here in post api response

```
$http.post(
 "http://api.worksiteclouddev.com/RestfulAPI/api/vw_PeopleListSiteAccess_Update/Get/", JSON.stringify(vm.content)
).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  //You should get your response here
},
function (error) {
  console.log("Something went wrong..." + error.status);
});
```

//For more you can create external service and call api in that service
//in you controller you can call that method

Comment: I *should* be getting it there, but I'm not. I'm not getting the **POST** response, but the **OPTIONS** response...

Comment: so then it is not because OPTIONS, options will always be there no matter what.

Comment: what are you getting in POST response