# Disable CORS check on angular 2 and Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, cors

I have an Angular 2 webapp compiled to Android with Ionic.

This app is making requests to my server and my server is configured with `access-control-allow-origin:*` and all is working fine.

As installed app, all requests are to a external domain, but once configured `CORS` I don't want duplicated Angular 2 requests using preflight `OPTION` to check `CORS`.

All my requests are sent two times, first as `OPTION` (check) and then as `GET` and is a huge performance issue to a regular app usage.

How can I disable preflight `OPTIONS` requests on Angular 2?

[image: duplicated requests]

Requests from "polyfills.js" are preflight `OPTIONS`.

Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs as per this, change content-type to anything but application/json.