# Error responde preflight and 405 same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i try to send some parameters using a web app in node, but show me this error's

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

[image: error app]

By the way, if use a app for make request, i use ARC, work fine

[image: arc]

[image: arc 2]

I check the cors in my node project, but don't say me nothing about the cors

```
$http.post('http://unicesarapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Materias1', 
          {"Id":1,"Nombre":"Prog. Haskell","Creditos":3,"IdGrupo":11,"Dia":"Miercoles","Hora":8,"Lugar":"Bloque B"}
    ).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: does that site allow CORS? (edit: looks like it does)

Comment: can you show the **request** headers of the failing request - looks like that site is choking on an OPTIONS preflight

Comment: Not, is that `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`, my back-end work C# in azure, maybe problem cors inside?

Comment: indeed, but the question is why is the browser wanting to make a preflight

Comment: I dont know, what recommended?

Comment: As I asked before can you show the **request** headers of the failing request - my guess is that you'll need to change the server to handle CORS preflight

Comment: here [image](https://imgur.com/a/10tzy)

Comment: AngularJS, by default, enables preflight requests (with request type `OPTIONS`) for cross-domain JSON requests. So, your server needs to support the `OPTIONS` request type for the necessary paths. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs), for a discussion on how to skip the preflight requests.

Comment: `AngularJS, by default, enables preflight requests` - I'd say "triggers" not "enables" - by adding headers that trigger the preflight, no doubt

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales - it's the content-type request header that triggers the pre-flight, so you will have to change the server to handle OPTIONS

Comment: @JaromandaX -- Indeed! Was just a slip of tongue :)

Comment: @31piy you should be using your fingers to type, not your tongue :p

Comment: @JaromandaX i need the change the options for this in the azure project?