# JSON Data Error 403

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I wanted to get JSON data from this link here:

[JSON Data](https://www.mobile.de/svc/r/models/3500?_jsonp=_loadModels&_lang=de)

when I open it in my Browser I get the data.
But when I want to get it with Angular HTTP-Client I get the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Then I got a chrome plugin called CORS with which the error reduced to:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.

So is it possible to get the data?

Comment: Your host from where you are requesting an ajax or http client needs to be whitelisted by API server so as to make cross origin request

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Oh okay so it won't be possible to get the data from localhost ... a pity

Comment: Possible but API server has to enable it for req origin host- localhost

Comment: CORS isn't a chrome plugin.  The server needs to be set up to use CORS and provide the necessary headers.

Comment: this post may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs