# Pyramid CORS for Ajax requests

Tags: python, cors, pyramid

Is it possible automatically add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to all responses which was initiated by ajax request (with header `X-Requested-With`) in Pyramid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved the problem using `set_request_factory`:

```
from pyramid.request import Request
from pyramid.request import Response

def request_factory(environ):
    request = Request(environ)
    if request.is_xhr:
        request.response = Response()
        request.response.headerlist = []
        request.response.headerlist.extend(
            (
                ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
                ('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            )
        )
    return request

config.set_request_factory(request_factory)
```

Comment: Doing this opens your server to attack from *ANY* domain; It would be much more secure to include a white-list of domains instead of a single wildcard.

Comment: honestduane makes a very good point here. If you are creating an API for public data (lets say weather information, or public transportation data) this may be the right thigh to do.

Comment: This is great, but it's often not sufficient. You will generally want to support OPTIONS requests too ([implementation](https://gist.github.com/mitchellrj/3721859)) as [browsers will convert POST to OPTIONS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12111936/509706) in some circumstances.

Comment: If you use a request factory, make sure that your request handlers take the response from the request (`response = request.response`) instead of making a new one (`response = Response(...)`). In the latter case your headers will not be included.

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways to do this: 1) a custom request factory like drnextgis showed, a NewRequest event handler, or a tween. A tween is almost certainly not the right way to do this, so I won't show that. Here is the event handler version:

```
def add_cors_headers_response_callback(event):
    def cors_headers(request, response):
        response.headers.update({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000',
        })
    event.request.add_response_callback(cors_headers)

from pyramid.events import NewRequest
config.add_subscriber(add_cors_headers_response_callback, NewRequest)
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue with enabling CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in a Pyramid application for AJAX requests. I resolved it by setting up a mechanism to automatically add CORS headers to all responses. Here's the complete solution:

1. **Create a CORS Preflight Predicate:**
   This predicate checks for CORS preflight (OPTIONS) requests by looking for specific request headers.

   ```py
   class CorsPreflightPredicate(object):
       def __init__(self, val, config):
           self.val = val

       def text(self):
           return 'cors_preflight = %s' % bool(self.val)

       phash = text

       def __call__(self, context, request):
           return (request.method == 'OPTIONS' and
                   'HTTP_ORIGIN' in request.headers.environ and
                   'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.headers.environ)
   ```
2. **Add a Route and View for Preflight Requests:**
   This route catches all URLs and processes them if they are CORS preflight requests.

   ```py
   def add_cors_preflight_handler(config):
       config.add_route('cors-options-preflight', '/{catch_all:.*}', cors_preflight=True)
       config.add_view(cors_options_view, route_name='cors-options-preflight', permission=NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED)

   def cors_options_view(context, request):
       response = request.response
       if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS' in request.headers.environ:
           response.headers.update({...})  # Add necessary CORS headers here
       return response
   ```
3. **Add a Response Callback:**
   The callback adds CORS headers to all responses for cross-origin requests.

   ```py
   def add_cors_to_response(event):
       request = event.request
       response = event.response
       if 'HTTP_ORIGIN' in request.headers.environ:
           response.headers.update({...})  # Add necessary CORS headers here
   ```
4. **Integrate CORS Handling in the Application:**
   Include the CORS setup in your Pyramid `Configurator` object.

   ```py
   def includeme(config):
       config.add_directive('add_cors_preflight_handler', add_cors_preflight_handler)
       config.add_route_predicate('cors_preflight', CorsPreflightPredicate)
       config.add_subscriber(add_cors_to_response, 'pyramid.events.NewResponse')

   # In your Pyramid configurator setup
   config.include('path.to.cors_module')
   config.add_cors_preflight_handler()
   ```

This approach effectively adds CORS headers to responses for AJAX requests and ensures compliance with CORS preflight requirements. Remember to replace `{...}` with actual CORS headers as per your requirements. For example, the following worked for me:

```
{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Type,Date,Content-Length,Authorization,X-Request-ID',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization ,X-Request-ID',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000',
            }
```

**Updated Answer:**

To handle CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in a Pyramid application for AJAX requests, you can use an event listener to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to responses for requests that include the `X-Requested-With` header. Here's how you can implement it:

1. **Create a New Event Subscriber:**
   Pyramid allows subscribing to various events in the request-response lifecycle. You can create an event subscriber for the `NewResponse` event, which is triggered just before a response is sent.
2. **Check for AJAX Requests:**
   In your event subscriber, check if the incoming request is an AJAX request by looking for the `X-Requested-With` header. If it's an AJAX request, add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response.
3. **Configure CORS Headers:**
   The value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can be `*` to allow all origins or a specific domain to restrict access. Be cautious with `*` as it allows any website to make requests to your server.
4. **Register the Event Subscriber:**
   Once the event subscriber is defined, you need to register it with your Pyramid configuration.

Here is a sample implementation:

```py
from pyramid.events import NewResponse
from pyramid.events import subscriber

@subscriber(NewResponse)
def add_cors_headers(event):
    request = event.request
    response = event.response
    if 'X-Requested-With' in request.headers:
        # You can replace '*' with a specific domain if needed
        response.headers.update({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
            # Add other headers as needed
        })

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    
    # Register the event subscriber
    config.add_subscriber(add_cors_headers, NewResponse)

    # ... rest of your Pyramid app setup ...

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

In this setup:

- The `add_cors_headers` function is an event subscriber for `NewResponse`.
- It checks if the `X-Requested-With` header is present, indicating an AJAX request.
- It then sets the necessary CORS headers on the response object.
- The event subscriber is registered in the `main` function with `config.add_subscriber`.

This will automatically add CORS headers to responses for AJAX requests in your Pyramid application, enabling cross-origin requests from client-side JavaScript. Adjust CORS settings based on your application's security requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I could send file with Ajax from a server to another server :

```
import uuid

from pyramid.view import view_config

from pyramid.response import Response


class FManager:

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name='f_manager', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
    def post(self):
        file_ = self.request.POST.items()
        content_type = str(file_[0][1].type).split('/')
        file_[0][1].filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + content_type[1]
        file_id = self.request.storage.save(file_[0][1])

        response = Response(body="{'data':'success'}")
        response.headers.update({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        })

        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
from pyramid.events import NewResponse, subscriber

@subscriber(NewResponse)
def add_cors_headers(event):
    if event.request.is_xhr:
        event.response.headers.update({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        })
```