# What are the steps to load cross domain url using ng-include in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I had referred this url [ng-include cross domain help angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805487/ng-include-cross-domain-help-angularjs)

added Access-Control-Allow-Origin also but still am unable to fix this problem

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

By using ajax you can not send request to cross domain, Whether you are using angularjs, jQuery or any other javascript framework.

You can send request within the same domain.