# 404 not found with api call - Angular to RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I am a newbie with Ruby on Rails and I am trying to figure out ways to connect Angular to RoR in a very simple way

Here is my service

```
mWebApp.service('mWebSrvc', function($http, $log) {
this.getCustomers = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/customers/'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.log('Done');
        angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
            $log.log(c.Title);
        });
        customers = data;
        return customers;
    });     
};
});
```

When I look under the Net tab in Firebug, I see OPTIONS /api/customers/ 404 Not Found, but if I click on the Response tab within, then I see the JSON file - WTF? And not the JSON tab - again, WTF?

Under Firebug's console -

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://numberForLocalHost:3000/api/customers/"
```

My Rails server is running in daemon mode - numberForLocalHost:3000 - is this what the issue might be? That it should be calling a true api

If I paste the URL above into any web browser, then I can see the JSON

As usual, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an `OPTIONS` request because your browser believes this is a cross origin request.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource) for example. Is your RoR app also serving your client side angular? If not, you should decide whether it can be (there shouldn't be a reason not to), or you need to reply to the [pre-flight `OPTIONS` request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests) from your server that you are seeing.

Comment: When I try to bring up my index.html file (Angular) through the localhost:3000, then it automatically goes to the RoR index.html.erb file, which has no angular. My index.html is in the root of the directory and calls files from the /angular/scripts/view/ directory - it is running on localhost:8888

Should I place the contents of the index.html file into the index.html.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue with my Rails + Angular app. I had my `cors` well set up in my rails app but still nothing, I still got a `404 not found` in the angular app. This could be the reason:
Perhaps you have `"angular-in-memory-web-api": '0.x.x'` in your `package.json` and also imported in your `app.module.ts`, as `InMemoryWebApiModule` and `InMemoryDataService`. These apparently intercept all calls to an API preventing them from ever reaching your back-end server. When I Removed those dependencies and their declarations, all of a sudden my app started working normally!

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41948613/2106474) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Denn for replying. I posted this question over five years ago and have since moved away from RoR. Sorry that I cannot remember the solution, but thank you for the info