# HTTP GET request changes into OPTIONS while adding headers in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

Following is the request i used so far

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function (data){})
    .error(function (data){})
```

works without any CORS issues. My server side Allows all origins, methods, all headers

when i add http header like

```
$http.get(url, { headers: { "USERID": user,  "SESSIONID": sessionId}})
```

the request changes into OPTIONS method when i see in chrome dev tools network tab

What is the reason for this? if it is expected then how to add custom http headers.

I have gone thru this link [angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource/12112294) but it didnt help

Here i am expecting that server should **allow different origins** . But it is allowing headers, only if i were in a same server. But not sure about this is by angular or by server side.

after headers

$http.get(url,{ headers: { "USERID": user, "SESSIONID": sessionId } })

in chrome dev tools i am seeing like

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

but without headers

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

When i do this in REST Client, i can send headers to the backend.

Comment: What are the changes you faced? 

var user = {
            name: 'foo name',
            age: 32
        };

        var sessionId = "somesessionid";

        $promise = $http.get('header', {
            headers: {
                "USERID": user,
                "SESSIONID": sessionId
            }
        });


I tried with this. and worked well.

Comment: edited the question please check

Comment: I think you are sending request to different server. The header method doesn't change to OPTION from GET if you request within the same server.

Comment: yeah its from cross origin. how to access a cross domain url? @Anik

Comment: use http://www.corsproxy.com/

in your code.

like this, 
$promise = $http.get('http://www.corsproxy.com/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http');

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl', headers: { "USERID": user,  "SESSIONID": sessionId}}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

will work.
    $http.get is a shortcut method.
Check the `config` in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, see for instance https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1585 .

A workaround is to use a jQuery request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same massive issue when trying to pass header in my get, where it changes get to options and wouldn't work. In order to make it work I added the following in my php api

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {  
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Auth-Token");    
  }
  exit;
} ?>
```

You can allow for any headers that you wish to pass.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For my particular problem with my C# Web API solution I had to have something handle the Options request.  Angular was sending a preflight request method OPTIONS which I did allow in my web.config with

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH" />
```

But that wasn't enough I also included a method to handle the Options Request and I returned nothing

```
[ResponseType( typeof( void ) )]
public IHttpActionResult OptionsPost() {
  return StatusCode( HttpStatusCode.NoContent );
}
```