# HTTP GET request changes into OPTIONS while adding headers in angular

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, cors

[HTTP GET request changes into OPTIONS while adding headers in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132246/http-get-request-changes-into-options-while-adding-headers-in-angular-js)

I have the same problem in Angular 4

Comment: The problem is because the app is at a domain, say `example.com`, different from the domain the service is at, say `api.com`. More details, refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821851/1850609

Answer (score 1):

Its called CORS, it has nothing to do with angular. Read up on the CORS spec, specifically the bit about simple request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If you do not want the options pre flight request to be triggered you must not add custom headers.

Have a look at this for info in which headers are cors safe:

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header