# angularJS sending OPTIONS instead of POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im stuck at this 2 days I can not find a solution. 
When im doing an AngularJS POST it Sends OPTIONS in the header and returns error from the API the code looks like this nothing special.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
$http.post(URL, JSON.stringify(data)).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error");
});
```

CORS is enabled on the API it has the Headers, when i do POST with fiddler or POSTMan in Chrome it works fine only when i use angularJS post it won't go thru.

why do i get `OPTIONS /SubmitTicket HTTP/1.1 instead of POST?`

What do i need to do to POST ? I have read about it it says something like CORS is adding OPTIONS header but why?

Comment: try using  $http.put

Comment: @Mico Sends OPTIONS again..

Comment: The HTTP methods POST and PUT aren't the HTTP equivalent of the CRUD's create and update. They both serve a different purpose. It's quite possible, valid and even preferred in some occasions, to use POST to create resources, or use PUT to update resources.

Comment: @Mico I just want to send JSON object and get a JSON object in return.. :/

Comment: Don't stringify the data... Angular does that for you!! `$http.post(URL, JSON.stringify(data)).` should be `$http.post(URL, data).` and don't set the `Content-Type`, angular also does this for you...

Comment: @CallumLinington fully Agreed. For more Please See the Example Below in my answer

Comment: @Orom I think that you have a typo in your code, The success function is not closed

Comment: @Eylen how i wish that was the error.. as I copy pasted the code i forgot to add } sorry

Comment: @Orom, OPTIONS request is triggered by some custom header. Most of the time it is "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" header. Can you list all headers from your POST request?

Comment: @MaksymDemidas Indeed it is because of application/json i think, that triggers the OPTIONS. But the API only accepts JSON, so i changed the Content-Type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded which resulted in a "Not found" error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the CORS requests, the browser always sends the OPTIONS request to server to know what methods are actually allowed. So this is the desired behaviour. This is so called: "Preflighted request", see: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ (section: "Preflighted requests")

Therefore in your case, you have to allow the OPTIONS method in 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' header of your CORS filter.

Comment: I have this in my API web config: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" /> 
Is this enough?

Comment: It might be. Be aware that from the security point of view, you have to enable only this options that are you actually using in your API. I usually have GET, PUT, POST and of course OPTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that angular initially sends an OPTIONS request to the server in order to ask the server if the full request is permissable.
The server will then respond with Headers specifying what is and is not allowed.

I guess this might be an issue with the server returning the wrong CORS headers.
You said that the server returns an error please post that error here.

See Preflighted CORS request at: http://www.staticapps.org/articles/cross-domain-requests-with-cors
and
[AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Comment: It only says Error 500, "Server Error Occured" how do i handle the OPTIONS request? that is something i don't get..

Comment: Make sure the API returns the following header 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' (to accept CORS from all sources) 

or
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: the address of your client'

Comment: indeed i have that too:  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

Comment: I had similar problems setting up a go backend API and angular.
The solution was to bypass the default request router and dispatcher  for OPTION requests.

These where the headers i ended up returning 

Access-Control-Allow-Origin : <origin>    
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization

Comment: Just aded thes to the API Web Config?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Content-Length,Accept-Encoding,X-CSRF-Token,Authorization

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS

Still not working, what does your Request header say application/json? or?

Comment: Change origin with the address of your requests origin. This is not really related with Angular anymore, so I guess you're better of googling "<backend type>  preflighted CORS" and maybe start a new question with proper tags.

Answer (score 0):

// Simple POST request example (passing data) :

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: @Callum Linington Updated My Sample

Answer (score 0):

Should only need to do this code to get it to work:

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
   .factory('someService', ['$http', someService]);

function someService() {
  var service = {
    save: save
  };

  var serviceUrl = '/some/Url';

  return service;

  function save(data) {
    $http.post(serviceUrl, data)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert(data);
          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("Error");
          });
  }
}
```

Then pull your `someService` into your controller and use:

```
someService.save(data);
```

Comment: var TestApp= angular.module("TestApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'someService']);
Is this the right way to pull it into the controller?

Comment: well, no... have you used much of angular before?

Comment: var MyController= function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $cookieStore, $interval, $routeParams, someService)
I googled it, but now it says:  Unknown provider: $someServiceProvider <- $someService <- MyController, what mI doing wrong? :/

Comment: can you not show your code? place it in the original question, feel free to change things that are client sensitive..

Comment: Unknown provider: someServiceProvider <- someService <- myController, well they kinda are sensitive.. but i will try..