# Angular $http.get sending two requests

Tags: angularjs, authorization

I am trying to send authorization info in a header using Angular $http.get.

If I call $http.get without config, it send the request only once.

As soon as I add a config with header info, it sends the request twice to the server. Once without the authorization header and the second time with.

Here is my code:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: authorization
    },
    withCredentials: true
};

$http.get(url, config).success(function (response) {
    $scope.records = validateResponse(response);
});
```

How can I get it to send only one request with the header information?

Comment: where have you added the config values ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularJS sending OPTIONS instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704283/angularjs-sending-options-instead-of-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the default http header of angularjs and make the request. 
`$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'token';`

Comment: $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization also send the request twice

Comment: The first request sent through is method OPTIONS and the second is GET