# AngularJS's $http.post() sends each time two AJAX requests, one without the data and one with

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, angular-http

I have a weird problem with AngularJS's `$http` service which, as far as I can see, no one else has.

Every time I use `$http.post()` to sent cross domain requests, I can see in the developer tools (network pane) that two different requests are being sent: one, without any data, and immediately after that another one is sent which has all the data and returns with the correct response from the server.

Here's an example:

```
$http.post(url+'getSiteList.php', {session_id: $scope.session_id(), withCredentials: true})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
....
```

Does anyone know what's causing this? I checked the code, and the $http.post method is only being called once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about how browsers manage CORS. When making a cross-domain request in angular, the browser will automatically make a HTTP OPTIONS request to the specified URL/URI it is called as "pre-flight" request or "promise".

As long as the remote source returns a HTTP status code of 200 and relevant details about what it will accept in the response headers, then the browser will go ahead with the original JavaScript call.