# Why my $.ajax showing "preflight is invalid redirect error"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried the following code in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and it was working. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.example.com/users/get',
   type: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'name-api-key':'ewf45r4435trge',
   },
   data: {
      'uid':36,
   },
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```

I got this error in my console as below, please advise.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/users/get Response
>   for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Answer (score 32):

I received the same error when I tried to call https web service as http webservice.

```
e.g when I call url 'http://api.example.com/users/get'
which should be 'https://api.example.com/users/get'
```

This error is produced because of redirection status 302 when you try to call http instead of https.

Answer (score 24):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource) goes over the exact same thing (although for angular) -- it is a CORS issue.

One quick fix is to modify each POST request by specifying one of the **'Content-Type'** header values which will not trigger a "preflight".  These types are:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

ANYTHING ELSE triggers a preflight.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.example.com/users/get',
   type: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'name-api-key':'ewf45r4435trge',
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   data: {
      'uid':36,
   },
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: My `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 6):

The error indicates that the preflight is getting a redirect response. This can happen for a number of reasons. *Find out where you are getting redirected to for clues to why it is happening. Check the network tab in Developer Tools.*

One reason, as @Peter T mentioned, is that the API likely requires HTTPS connections rather than HTTP and all requests over HTTP get redirected. The `Location` header returned by the `302` response would say the same url with `http` changed to `https` in this case.

Another reason might be that your authentication token is not getting sent, or is not correct. Most servers are set up to redirect all requests that don't include an authentication token to the login page. Again, check your `Location` header to see if this is where you're getting sent and also take a look to make sure the browser sent your auth token with the request.

Oftentimes, a server will be configured to always redirect requests that don't have auth tokens to the login page - including your preflight/`OPTIONS` requests. This is a problem. Change the server configuration to permit `OPTIONS` requests from non-authenticated users.

Answer (score 5):

Please set http content type in header and also make sure the server is authenticating CORS. This is how to do it in PHP:

```
//NOT A TESTED CODE
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
```

Please refer to:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Its a server-side PHP (which may not what your server app is using). These headers are sent by the server and are required to make CORS work.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` sometimes doesn't work with `*` and you need to explicitly set the origin where the calling code is running from. Specifically when trying to include credentials (auth cookies). See [this table](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-xhr-credentials) on the Fetch Spec.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that POST requests need trailing slashes '/'.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it kept me up for days. At the end, I realised that my URL pointing to the app was wrong altogether.
example:

```
URL: 'http://api.example.com/'
URL: 'https://api.example.com/'.
```

If it's http or https verify.
Check the redirecting URL and make sure it's the same thing you're passing along.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, though the problem was that I had a typo in the url

```
url: 'http://api.example.com/TYPO'
```

The API had a redirect to another domain for all URL's that is wrong (404 errors).

So fixing the typo to the correct URL fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by the exact opposite of @ehacinom. My Laravel generated API didn't like the trailing '/' on POST requests. Worked fine on localhost but didn't work when uploaded to server.