# Fetch API cannot load the url. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: post, fetch, http-status-code-302

I use fetch to call a post service and I get the error `Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/user/login`. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)'. `Status code: 302 Found.` The variable 'data' is a json `object {email: "batman@dc.com", password: "111"}`

```
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/login', {
        method: 'post',
        body : JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType : 'json'
    })
```

Answer (score 6):

There maybe several possible reasons you are getting this error.

- As @toomuchdesign mentioned a possible reason why is because you might need to make a request through `https` instead of `http`.
- Try appending a `/` to the url. '`http://localhost:8080/user/login/`' instead of '`http://localhost:8080/user/login`'.
  As it could be redirecting from a `preflight/OPTIONS` request.

Comment: Similar problem, got resolved by point 2 i.e. appending '/'. Can you elaborate more as why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the url you're hitting is responding with a redirect to another url.

In my case I was requesting a resource trough `http` instead of `https`, so the server was responding with a redirect to https protocol.

More hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645511/why-my-ajax-showing-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-error).