# Works fine on postman and not working on AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, rest, api, codeigniter

```
var username = 'xxxx';
var password = 'zzzz';

var xmlstring="<root><request><AADHAAR_ID>aaaaaaa</AADHAAR_ID><NAME>hhhhhhh</NAME><DOB></DOB><MOBILENO></MOBILENO><FLAG>QVVUSA==</FLAG><RESPONSE_CODE></RESPONSE_CODE><ERROR_CODE></ERROR_CODE><OTP></OTP><PIN></PIN><DEPT>aswww</DEPT><VENDORID>MTAwSFBN</VENDORID></request></root>";

  function make_base_auth(username, password) {
  var tok = username + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        async: true, 
        dataType:"xml", 
        contentType: "application/xml",
        url: 'http://test/test/test?reqXml='+xmlstring,

       beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
    },
        success: function(){console.log('success');
          alert('success');
        },
       error: function(data) {console.log('error');
    console.log(data);
 }
    });
```

Hi, above is my code please tell what i have missed.I'm attempting to do a simple PSTrequest from my local server and this request requires an Authorization header in order to function correctly. I have performed the POST request and retrieved the data successfully in Postman,  Ajax results in a "Invalid HTTP status code 302" error and  My error is XMLHttpRequest cannot load .....Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Answer (score 1):

[Why my $.ajax showing "preflight is invalid redirect error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645511/why-my-ajax-showing-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-error)
Possible answer check link.

I think you have possible solution try to pass header or change http to https. please refer link for better solution.