# Web Api 2 Handle OPTIONS Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have `Web Api 2` backend hosted on Azure and `AngularJs` forntend. I understand that some of `HTTP request` use pre-check with `OPTIONS request`. My question is how to implement backend that way, that all `OPTIONS requests` will return 200 if there is some action in controller that will handle following `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/...`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Non elegant way to solve this task is adding in each controller manually

```
[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,DELETE");

    return resp;
}
```

*Or override MessageHandlers*

```
 public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
  protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
  HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
      {
         var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

          var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;              
          var supportedMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions.Where(d => 
             {  
                var controller = d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                return string.Equals(
                    controller, controllerRequested, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            })
          .Select(d => d.HttpMethod.Method)
          .Distinct();

      if (!supportedMethods.Any())
         return Task.Factory.StartNew(
             () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

      return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            resp.Headers.Add(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", string.Join(",", supportedMethods));

            return resp;
        });
}

return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

  }
}
```

**and then in config**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new OptionsHttpMessageHandler());
```

even second option is not perfect though... no native build in support

Comment: or inherit from your own base class which contains your public HttpResponseMessage Options() method:    public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue as you, the so called Preflight request, and I figured out that this might be related to a misconfiguration on the Web.Conf file. 
Comment out or remove, if present, the line containing the "remove" of the OPTIONSVerbHandler.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> -->
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You are a hero!