# IONIC 1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, cordova, http, ionic-framework, server

I can not solve this error.
I try with:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

adding headers

- Access-Control-Allow-Headers : "*"
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods : "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*"

And It did not work.

Please help

[image]

Comment: Please can you provide the js making the request

Comment: Aggregate failed request @Pete

Answer (score 1):

can you provide more details about your question?

4xx is client error, 
405 maybe a GET request on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

So can you check whether your request type is wrong?

Comment: Aggregate failed request @Linerd

Comment: @AlexQuintero I see your requestTravelAllCustomers request seems to be "OPTIONS" in your error log, and I find someone else already post the solution which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404, hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with whitelist

- make sure you are not posting from your service(post from your controller)
- make sure your server responds with a 200 status code when the response is options