# send https request from angular to nodejs. Can't send any data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, http-post

So first I have my angular app:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app.controllers', []);

app.config(function($httpProvider){
   delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
});
```

And here is an angular controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

   $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'https://xxx-xxx.c9users.io:xxxx/api/registerUser',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
       data: { test: 'something' }
   });

}]);
```

And then there's my nodejs code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
   next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
});

app.post('/api/registerUser', function (req, res) {
   //req.body.test do something..
});
```

So whenever I try to send this request to the node server. I get the following error in my browser console:

*OPTIONS https://xxx-xxx.c9users.io:xxx/api/registerUser *

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx-xxx.c9users.io:xxxx/api/registerUser. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404*

And the server never gets the request. BUT, if I just call it like this:

```
$http.post('https://xxx-xxx.c9users.io:xxxx/api/registerUser');
```

The server wont have any trouble receiving the request, but there's no data though. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe missing a route for OPTIONS? What happened when you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404

Comment: @OlaEkdahl I've tried it now, and added it up above. But it had no effect im afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are requesting from other domain you must allow Cross Origin Resources from the server side.

Here is the small node snippet of how to turn on CORS using express framework.

**NodeJS Code Snippet**

```
allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: Ok the if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }  was what fixed this for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it seems to me you are missing the options method.
Adding this also:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

Comment: I've now added the following line, but it had no effect.