# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 on angular post request

Tags: angularjs

I am having an $http request in my localhost which is calling a url of some api. I am getting an error on executing  the call

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

Can I do anything using angular so that I can fix this issue? I have CROS plugin of chrome to allow cross origin request

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data:data1,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',                 
                }
            })
```

Comment: Whats the server side script?

Comment: 403 is forbidden access...

Comment: It's the server side script/code that needs to add allow origin to their code.

Comment: Server side is java but I can not do anything on that

Comment: possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082492/how-to-send-post-request-using-http-from-angular-http?noredirect=1#47082492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's how I figured this out. It all has to do with CORS policy. Before the POST request, Chrome was doing a preflight OPTIONS request, which should be handled and acknowledged by the server prior to the actual request. Now this is really not what I wanted for such a simple server. Hence, resetting the headers client side prevents the preflight:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
});
```

The browser will now send a POST directly. Hope this helps a lot of folks out there... My real problem was not understanding CORS enough.

Link to a great explanation: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Kudos to this answer for showing me the way.
[AngularJS POST Fails: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404)

Comment: Is there a solution like this that will work in jQuery?

Comment: How to do this in Angular2?

Answer (score 5):

If you using java restful controller as your server.
You can refer to https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

I added @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")  on my controller and it works.
Basically, you cannot do anything in the client side.

Lin

Comment: This worked for me. Any risks with keeping this annotation on the controller methods in the Java code long-term?

Answer (score 1):

I have this code in angularjs:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/employee/'
        , $scope.alumno
        ,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
        ).success(function(data){

            if ( data.err === false ) {
                $scope.actualizado = true;

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $scope.actualizado = false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                }, 3500);

            };
        });
```

My API have this data:

```
//Add employee:
Url: http://localhost:8080/employee
Type request: POST
Add a new employee:
{
 "firstName": "Javier",
 "lastName": "Piedra",
}`
```

I use chrone with extension for available CORS for the GET all perfect but post sample this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/employee/. Response for 
preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

In my app.config use:

```
app.config( function($routeProvider,$httpProvider){

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

Maybe this can be a solution for your issue.

Regards

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16301631)

Comment: Thanks. I can´t ask: You have reached your question limit . Regards