# how to send post request using http from @angular/http

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, http-headers

I am using following code to send a post request

```js
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    private _options = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
           return this.http.post('http://localhost:56451/map',
              { "username": username, "password": password },
              this._options);
    }
}
```

however I am getting following error in vscode

```
Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types 
 of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Property 'forEach' 
 is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.
```

Please help clarify associated concepts

Comment: use Headers from @angular/http instead of HttpHeaders if you are using angular 4 `new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });`

Comment: Exactly, it removed the error, but I think there is something wrong with my approach or code, since I am getting following response ------->  Failed to load http://localhost:56451/map: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Comment: thats another issue, I've seen couple of questions regarding this on SO, search for it you will get an answer for sure!

Comment: sure!, Thank you, looking for it

Comment: I would imagine you're getting the 403 as you're providing headers in the POST request, so Angular is sending an OPTIONS request first, which your server -side logic isn't set up for. You'd need to enable CORS on the server otherwise you'll get 403/405.

Comment: Perhaps informative: discussion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728775/type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptionsargs/44728776?noredirect=1#comment81114325_44728776

Comment: Please update your question with the findings from the comments above

Comment: sure @wdanda, Thank you for asking

Comment: where is this.options defined?

Comment: edited, options is now defined, it was typo introduced while updating question from angular docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing classes: `HttpHeaders` goes with `HttpClient`, which *replaces* `Http` since 4.3.

The other comments about 403 are worth investigating, but at a minimum, do this:

```typescript
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    private _options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };

    // Inject HttpClient, not Http
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
           return this.http.post('http://localhost:56451/map',
              { username, password },
              this._options);
    }
}
```

Note that you can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the post body (when your object key name is the same as the variable name you are replacing it with).

Comment: Thank you for answer @msanford, I am working on it, will update as I come to solution

Comment: working on it,perhaps this link is relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404

Comment: when I changed Http to HttpClient, I get following error in console, No provider for HttpClient, Can you please show some light on related concept

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain You need to include `HttpClientModule` in an `@NgModule`'s `imports: []` list.

Comment: Absolutely @msanford, so I guess the trick to know the corresponding module name for the component or directive, is to read the corresponding tutorial properly

Comment: Or is there any other way or documentation, to determine which module contains the component we are trying to use

Comment: @Anuj That's a weird pattern, why do `Observable.create(observer => { this.myhttp.post`? Do like the example.

Comment: @Anuj You mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728775/type-headers-has-no-properties-in-common-with-type-requestoptionsargs/44728776 ?

Comment: As for "I'm using it in a service" still, I've never seen anyone create an observer like that. You should very likely just `return this.myhttp.post`

Comment: @Anuj This is getting long for a comment thread: *probably ask a new question.* It's hard to understand code in a comment like this.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to CORS, Even though I have enabled CORS chrome plugin, still because I was specifying options, a preflight response was send to server which was rejected

The solution which helped was putting CORS annotation on my rest controller in Java, so probably only server side code can help here

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")  <------ this solved the issue of post request getting failed
@RestController
public class ProductController {...
```

Comment: I am using angular with asp.net core web api . I have also enabled cors . get request succeeds but post request gives me CORS error access denied. Any idea _ thanks