# Ionic - $http works in mobile device but in browser it shows CORS and preflight error

Tags: http, browser, ionic-framework, android-webview, preflight

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic framework. I use $http (POST with custom header) and When I try

**ionic serve**

in browser(chrome, firefox, ...), i am getting

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.**

error. If I enable CORS plugin in chrome and try the same, i am getting

**Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405**

error.

But everything works when I install it in my mobile(Android/IOS) using

**ionic run android**

or

**ionic run ios**

What is making my browser to restrict $http and why my mobile allows it.?
Is Webview different from browser?

**for info:**
 - I am using (default) cordova plugins - console, device, splashscreen, statusbar, whitelist, keyboard

please help me here. Without proper understanding, I can not simply build mobile app. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

I am using REST API which handles custom Header requests. I am not allowed to modify the API code as of now, because it is running fine for native android app for a long time. The issue is when I am using Ionic and to my surprise it works in my Samsung Tab and IPad (when I run without livereload mode).

All I wanted to know is, what is causing my Browser to restrict and my Mobile device to work?

Isn't WebView in mobile device have the security policy like in Browsers?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why my mobile app works fine but not in browser?

I am using cordova-plugin-whitelist in my Ionic project. It implements a whitelist policy for navigating the application webview. [check source](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html)

To make browser work, define proxy in my ionic.config.json. But this is just a work around. For production we should make the server to allow it explicitly to whitelist the API call. [check source](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html)

Answer (score -1):

@Naveen - Ionic wrote a blog paper about the differences between browser and in-app handling of http origin header: http://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. :)