# Sending form data to api through $http in angular js

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to send the registration form data to an api that registers the user and provides the success response. I am getting the following error while try to send the data through $http

```
/ringleader/www/#!/register:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://72.5.146.113/portal-app/API/addRingLeader/?0=f&1=i&10=s&100=c&101=i&…
87=d&88=g&89=%26&9=%3D&90=p&91=r&92=o&93=d&94=u&95=c&96=t&97=%3D&98=S&99=o. 
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Here is my controller

```
.controller('loginController',function($scope,authService){
$scope.login = function(data){
    authService.login(data).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.status + " ------ "+JSON.stringify(response));
    },function(err){
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}

})

.controller('registerController',function($scope,authService){
$scope.register = function(data){
    authService.register(data).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.status + " ------ "+JSON.stringify(response));
    },function(err){
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
})
```

and this is my service

```
.factory('authService',function($http){
return{
    register : function(data){
        return $http({
            url: 'http://72.5.146.113/portal-app/API/addRingLeader/',
            method: 'POST',
            params: $.param({
                firstname : data.firstname,
                lastname : data.lastname,
                email : data.email,
                mobile : data.mobile,
                password : data.password,
                product : "Social"
            }),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
    },
    login : function(data){
        return $http({
            url: 'http://72.5.146.113/portal-app/API/signIn/',
            method: 'POST',
            params: $.param(data),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
    }
}
})
```

and this is how the response should look like.
[image]

Comment: did u check cors is enabled in server? you can refer this link https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: You should check in network whether you are getting Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true  as respone when you send options method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404

Comment: The server is maintained by third party I don't have access to the server. the CORS is enabled in my browser(chrome). @Nayas Subramanian

Comment: Is CORS enabled in server? It looks not...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS POST Fails: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404)

Comment: @Sam you can check whether cors is enabled from network tab. You can see two request calls when u trigger a create in network. In the first response you can see whether Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true.