# What is the difference between redirect and next in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I quite don't understand the difference between these two:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  next();
 //ROUTE 1
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/some');
  //ROUTE 2
});

app.get('/some', function(req, res) {
  res.send("success");
  //ROUTE 3
});
```

When I try making request to `ROUTE 1`, I get response **success** but `ROUTE 2` doesn't show this response. Why is that?

What I want to do is:

Every request should pass from ROUTE **1** and the control should be handled to a **SPECIFIC** route, which I would write in it ROUTE `if-else` statement (not like `next()`, which sends control to next MATCHING route).

For example:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if(x==y){
    //call SPECIFIC route 3 
  } else {
    // call SPECIFIC route 4 (another route)
    //ROUTE 1
});
```

I tried to do it with redirect but it's not working.

Thank you.

EDIT:

- Routes would be: `/checkIfSession` exists. I would use express-session to check if user's username exists or not in session.

If exists, I want to send control to `if` otherwise `else`.

Assume the requests are:

1. http://198.168.43.200:3000/checkIfSession
2. http://198.168.43.200:3000/some

(I will call only 1st request).

EDIT 2: I tried following but I don't get any response when I request:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if(2==2){
        res.redirect("/session");
    } else {
        res.end("else");
   }
});

app.get("/session", function(req, res){
    res.write("session");
    res.end();
});

app.get("/some", function(req, res){
    res.write("some");
    res.end();
});
```

Request: **/some**

Comment: What **exact** uris are you using to try this?

Comment: what is x and y in your example some variable in your server side or something you are getting from the client side ? and I you want all your routes to go through a particular condition you can use a `middleware`

Comment: `res.redirect` will work for your requirement. No need of next. But If you mention * ,any request will go into this route , regardless of your definition of that route and hence you may end up in an infinite redirection in your case. eg : if you have defined /test after * then,request to /test will be given to *.

Comment: Please check the edits.

Comment: @vinothh I will handle the infinite thing. 2ndly, redirect is done on server side or client side?

Comment: Looking at your edits I agree with @warl0ck you want to implement some form of `middleware`.

Comment: Okay, I would use a middleware like `app.use(function())`, but still inside that middleware, I would need to check for if and else and redirect to a specific route. What should I use?

Comment: So now just to be sure you want, all your requests to pass through some king of check i.e. if the session is valid or not ??

Comment: @warl0ck exactly. Then I would use control statement to "redirect" to some another route(s)

Comment: @VikasKumar instead of this you can pass the function as well before sending any details of that protected route.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @VikasKumar Redirection is done by the server. Use express session to store the user-name. If user exists redirect him to your page. But put a check in that route too, that whether the user exists.

Comment: @warl0ck your last comment? I quite didn't understand. Also, can I use redirect as told by @vinoth?

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you want your routes to go through some kind of authentication first you can use `middleware` in your routes.

Below is sample code:

```
app.get('/some', checkSession, function(req, res) {
  res.send("success");
});

// this is the middleware function

function checkSession(req, res, next) {
    // do your checking here
    if (x===y) {
        next();
        //continue users access to protected API
    } 
    else {
        res.redirect('/');
        // redirect user to the default login page
    }
}
```

In this above example there are `2 Cases`

**Case1**:

`x === y` as from your given example I'am assuming users is logged in, so when the user is accessing `/some` section of your website he will receive `Success` from the server.

This is the use of your `next()` function i.e. it continues the execution of that api or sends the data whatever the user is requesting. Something similar to `continue` in your programming.

**Case2**:

`x!==y` now this will be the case where user is `not authenticated or logged in` and user is still trying to access the `/some` section of your website. In this case user will be redirected to `login` page of whatever you have designed for your website for him/her to re-enter his/her credentials.

Here your `redirect` function redirects the user without sending any data. Something similar to the `break`.

Comment: This finally suggests that I should use res.redirect to "call" a specific route? This was my fundamental query.

Comment: see here next() is continuing the access of user to the api, whereas redirect
 is sending the user to that page. I'll update the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Well now I'm getting this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.43.200:3000/some. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: I am making this request from angularjs's ajax

Comment: atleast is now your routes are working fine ?? c=you can check them by using `console.log` to make sure and as for the error you are describing see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404

Comment: I'll respond you soon.

Comment: sure take your time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147282/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-warl0ck).

Comment: can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712538/cant-save-express-session-in-nodejs

Comment: sure, but first is this question of your answered ??