# Get json and save with php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

I'm trying to get a json coming from an application and saved in the database, I'm trying to do this with php and mysql.

I need to get a json and then save it on the bank. I can not get json and pass it on some variable. Save the variable in the database I could do.

I created a simple table in the bank and this I created is simple, it's just to learn.

Receives_json.php

```
   <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

$assunto_contato = $_POST["assunto_contato"];
$comentario_contato = $_POST["comentario_contato"];
$nome_contato = $_POST["nome_contato"];
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$conn = new mysqli("", "", "", "");

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO contato VALUES ('$assunto_contato', '$comentario_contato', '$nome_contato', '$data')";

$stm = $conn -> prepare($sql_insert);

if ($stm->execute()){
    $retorno = array("retorno" => 'YES');
 } else {
    $retorno = array("retorno" => 'NO');
 }

 echo json_encode($retorno);

 $stm->close();
 $conn->close();
?>
```

I'm getting json from angularjs, that angularjs function sending json:

```
    .controller('contatoController', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $http, $ionicPlatform, $state) {
     $scope.contato = {};
     $scope.Enviar = function() {
         var linkContato = 'http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php'
         $http.post(linkContato, {
             "assunto_contato": "$scope.contato.assunto",
             "comentario_contato": "$scope.contato.comentario"
         });
         console.log()
         $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
             disableBack: true
         })
         $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'Sua mensagem foi enviada'
         }).then(function() {
             $state.go('app.home');
         })
         console.log($scope.contato.assunto);
         console.log($scope.contato.comentario);
     }
 })
```

But I can not get the json that is coming from angularjs in php, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed again.

Receives_json.php

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$assunto_contato = $_POST["assunto_contato"];
$comentario_contato = $_POST["comentario_contato"];
$nome_contato = $_POST["nome_contato"];
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$conn = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
$sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO contato(assunto_contato, comentario_contato, nome_contato, data_contato)';
$sql_insert .= 'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stm = $conn -> prepare($sql_insert);
$stm->bind_param("ssss", $assunto_contato, $comentario_contato, $nome_contato, $data);

if ($stm->execute()){
    $retorno = array("retorno" => 'YES');
 } else {
    $retorno = array("retorno" => 'NO');
 }

 echo json_encode($retorno);

 $stm->close();
 $conn->close();
?>
```

my angularjs

```
.controller('contatoController', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $http, $ionicPlatform, $state) {

  $scope.contato = {};

  $scope.Enviar = function(){

            var linkContato = 'http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php'
        $http({
           method:'POST',
           url:linkContato,
           data:{ 
               "assunto_contato" : $scope.contato.assunto, 
               "comentario_contato" : $scope.contato.comentario 
               },
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
          }).then(function(resp){
             console.log(resp); //success
          }, function(error){
              //if error
          });

            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Sua mensagem foi enviada'
            }).then(function(){
              $state.go('app.home');
            })


            console.log($scope.contato.assunto);
            console.log($scope.contato.comentario);
  }

})
```

In the database is generating a record, but I can not get the variables coming from angularjs. And it's not giving any errors on the chrome console.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in php?

Comment: Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in php? @jesus-carrasco

Comment: Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in php? @vivz

Comment: Your js is working now? What error are you getting now ? @Lucas

Comment: My question is how can I serialize it? Because when I'm giving console.log this is showing this:Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

Comment: Ask this as a separate question. You have already asked too many questions. Please do accept any answer that helped you reach one step ahead in solving the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, my problem was in php. I got it sorted out. @Vivz

Answer (score 0):

You have to call post method correctly with desired object. So change your code the below way and access the response coming from your API call the following way

```
var data = {
     "assunto_contato": $scope.contato.assunto,
     "comentario_contato": $scope.contato.comentario
 }
 data = JSON.stringify(data);
 var linkContato = 'http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php';
 $http.post(linkContato, data).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response.data);
 }).catch(function(error) {

 });
```

For more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: This usage is not in the documentation for the $http object. Can you post a source please?

Comment: It is from the $http documentation '$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);'

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion. According to the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http you're not using $http right. have a look at the docs there and you should end up with something like:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the angularjs, to test. I did as @Vivz said. I think he's like this:

```
.controller('contatoController', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $http, $ionicPlatform, $state) {

      $scope.contato = {};

      $scope.Enviar = function(){

                  var data = {
                       "assunto_contato": $scope.contato.assunto,
                       "comentario_contato": $scope.contato.comentario
                   }
                   data = JSON.stringify(data);
                   var linkContato = 'http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php';
                   $http.post(linkContato, data).then(function(response) {
                       console.log(response.data);
                   }).catch(function(error) {

                   });

                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableBack : true
                })

                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Sua mensagem foi enviada'
                }).then(function(){
                  $state.go('app.home');
                })
      }

})
```

But now he is giving this error:

OPTIONS http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php 500 (Internal Server Error) - ionic.bundle.js:25005

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Comment: The first error is caused maybe because your php is not expecting what you are sending. Unfortunately I don't know php that well to verify if your php code is working or not. But your 2nd error can be fixed by checking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404. Try to solve the second one, maybe the first one will also resolve.

Answer (score 0):

change your $http like this one..
  i detect you was '' the $scope values. there are wrong.

```
.controller('contatoController', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, 
$ionicHistory, $http, $ionicPlatform, $state) {

  $scope.contato = {};

  $scope.Enviar = function(){

        var linkContato = 'http://apps.greenonetec.com.br/insert_contato.php'
        $http({
           method:'POST',
           url:linkContrato,
           data:{ 
               "assunto_contato" : $scope.contato.assunto, 
               "comentario_contato" : $scope.contato.comentario 
               },
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
          }).then(function(resp){
             console.log(resp); //success
          }, function(error){
              //if error
          });


})
```

Comment: about the prefligh check allow headers , allow methods allow origin in your configuration, some .htacces rules, or in your index.php