# Angular 5+ post to nodejs error

Tags: angular, post, http-status-code-404, postman

So, I have looked at some answers and will try to be as complete as I can as to what I have tried.   Being a new fish here, I did look first but did not find a satisfactory answer.

First the problem.  I am attempting to post id, password to an endpoint called obviously enough **'/login'** which is running on node.  I have run the endpoint using postman and it does work..  I have tried with the httpOptions header set to json (thank you stackoverflow) but I am still getting the 404.    I have for this purpose coding in the standard console logging to see where the flow is and it does not even get to the route.post..

**Failed to load http://localhost:3000/login: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.**

First the angular side of things. As a **service**

```
public login(user, passwd) {
console.log('url %s user %s passwd %s', this.url, user, passwd);

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

this.http.post(this.url, {
    id: user,
    password: passwd
  },
  httpOptions)

  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error occured %o', err);
    }
  );
 }
```

Now the node code.. I placed a get here as well in case for some reason I was firing the wrong thing - i am not  even getting the console logs.

```
app.route('/login')
.get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
    console.log ('login get');
    res.json({login : false});
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
})
.post((request, response) => {

    console.log("sesssion is %o", request.session);

    // taken from personal code I wrote a few years back
    console.log('request %o', request.query);
    let username = request.query.id;
    let password = request.query.password;

    console.log('user %s pass %s', username, password);
```

I do fall all the way through to my 404 url not found code.

```
// route for handling 404 requests(unavailable routes)
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
console.log(' some sort of error ');
res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
});
```

I get from here the message "Sorry Can't find that" which I would expect if I was giving the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is an answer for this and it is contained within the least voted on answer of 2 [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404/44343484?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa/%22answer%22)

A billion thank's to the guy.  In a nutshell add the following to the server side CORS scripting..

```
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") 
    res.send(200);
else 
    next();
```