# AngularJS performs OPTIONS request instead of GET and got 405 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I send `GET` request to .NET Web API application from Angular but I got 405 error.

When I send same request to same address on POSTMAN, everythings looks correctly.

My api codes

```
public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
{
    response.error = false;
    response.data = db.Users;
    response.message = result.message;
    return Ok(response);
}
```

And my Angular codes are below

```
service.getCategories = function (callback) {

    var url = $rootScope.servicePath + "/categories";

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            callback(response.data)
        });

};
```

Result of request:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added this line to head of my controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Problem solved.