# Setting default headers for all http requests is not working

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have a CORS problem when I try to do a request to an external API. 
I tried to add the token to all requests like this:

```
    var dApp = angular.module("app", []);
    dApp.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization =  'APP token=TOKEN';
    });
```

The `Authorization` string is defined as defined on API.
If I check the headers of the request I can't see my string and the return code is `404 OPTIONS`.
I tried to do the request with Postman and it works.

It returns 404 but the error in the console is:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=master&artist=The%20Strokes&format=album&callback=. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

If I pass the token on the url it works, but only with GET and POST requests.

I already read the question [Angular.js performs an options http request for CORS resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource?rq=1) but I didn't found the solution for my problem

[image: As you can see there aren't my headers]

Comment: A 404 means that the resource doesn't exist on the server. The URL is incorrect.

Comment: I tried to do the request with Postman and it works. 
It returns 404 but the error in the console is:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=master&artist=The%20Strokes&format=album&callback=. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

If I pass the token on the url it works, but only with GET and POST requests.

Comment: Reading https://www.discogs.com/developers/, this API doesn't seem to support CORS. You should use JSONP to access the API.

Comment: Then API is not CORS enabled. Since you need authorization for it you will have to use a proxy

Comment: Using a proxy is the right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for FireFox:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
```

However, the best way of doing this in Chrome I know about is by running the application with **--disable-web-security**, which is not good, since, besides the fact that it is insecure, you will have to tell your users to disable their web security, which is not really a good idea.

You can do it as follows:

- you write a server-side API which gets the request parameters
- the API will forward them to the third-party server
- the API will send the response to the client-side