# Angular2 OPTIONS method sent when asking for http.GET

Tags: http, cors, angular

I'm trying to add [basic authentification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) to my angular2 app.

```
public login() {
    // Set basic auth headers
    this.defaultHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password));

    console.log('username', this.username)
    console.log('password', this.password)
    console.log(this.defaultHeaders)

    // rest is copy paste from monbanquetapiservice
    const path = this.basePath + '/api/v1/development/order';        

    let req = this.http.get(path, { headers: this.defaultHeaders });
    req.subscribe(
        _ => { },
        err => this.onError(err)
    );
}
```

What I expect to see is a GET request with the `Authorization`header I put.

But what I see is first a **OPTIONS** with this headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/development/order HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
```

Since my server doesn't allow **OPTIONS** on this url, I get an error.

I know that some methods like PUT or POST send first an OPTIONS method to preflight the request, but GET doesn't.

Why does angular2's http send a OPTIONS first?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request

Comment: This is similar enough to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource

Comment: Make sure there is a trailing slash, as mentioned here in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062221/6748184

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is the way CORS works (when using cross domain requests). With CORS, the remote Web application (here the one with domain mydomain.org) chooses if the request can be served thanks to a set of specific headers.

The CORS specification distinguishes two distinct use cases:

- **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.
- **Preflighted requests**. When the ‘simple requests’ use case doesn’t apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

It's not Angular2 that sends the OPTIONS request but the browser itself. It's not something related to Angular.

For more details, you could have a look at this article:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Comment: I am sending a `GET` request, but I still have this preflight. I know about preflight for PUT and sometimes POST methods, but GET shouldn't have one. That's why I thought it was some angular thing which added this OPTIONS preflight

Comment: I think that it's because of the `Authorization` header... Because of it, you're in the case of a preflight request and not a simple request.

Comment: In fact, that's the case when you have a custom header (not something sent under the hood by the browser)...

Comment: GET requests also use preflight if you have a content-type that is not in the list above, e.g application/json. I successfully avoided the OPTIONS request by using text/plain, even with a JSON source.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier 's reply here is honestly an answer in and of itself. Removing extra headers that I was adding by default in my interceptor was the culprit.

Comment: I had an Angular app specific issue where touching the request with `HttpInterceptor` caused it create a OPTIONS requets intead of plain GET. More information here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367478/315168

Answer (score 7):

[Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

That is a CORS preflight request that is generated by the browser itself.

See also
- [How to disable OPTIONS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)

The server needs to be configured to support CORS requests, only then the actual `GET` request is sent by the browser after the `OPTIONS` request.

See also
- ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

> **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**
>
> Indicates whether or not the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is true.  When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request can be made using credentials.  Note that simple GET requests are not preflighted, and so if a request is made for a resource with credentials, if this header is not returned with the resource, the response is ignored by the browser and not returned to web content.

Comment: Nice answer, but something strange happened to me, when I issue HTTP request to GitHub.com API, there is no preflight request, but when I do it with my own service API, all requests have preflight request! Do you know what's the reason?

Comment: GitHub probably provides the expected headers in the response, while your service API doesn't.

Comment: Yes, It's possible. But how does Chrome know? It at least should make the first Preflight request to consider

Comment: If a preflight request is made depends on some criteria. See Thierry's answer about simple and preflight request.